# Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, dom-events

In the following example code, I attach an `onclick` event handler to the span containing the text "foo". The handler is an anonymous function that pops up an `alert()`.

However, if I assign to the parent node's `innerHTML`, this `onclick` event handler gets destroyed - clicking "foo" fails to pop up the alert box.

Is this fixable?

```
<html>
 <head>
 <script type="text/javascript">

  function start () {
    myspan = document.getElementById("myspan");
    myspan.onclick = function() { alert ("hi"); };

    mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    mydiv.innerHTML += "bar";
  }

 </script>
 </head>

 <body onload="start()">
   <div id="mydiv" style="border: solid red 2px">
     <span id="myspan">foo</span>
   </div>
 </body>

</html>
```

Comment: This question is related to the 'appending new fields to a form erases user input' problem. The selected answer fixes both of these problems very nicely.

Comment: Event delegation can be used to tackle this problem.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Unfortunately, assignment to `innerHTML` causes the destruction of all child elements, even if you're trying to append.  If you want to preserve child nodes (and their event handlers), you'll need to use [DOM functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference):

```
function start() {
    var myspan = document.getElementById("myspan");
    myspan.onclick = function() { alert ("hi"); };

    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    mydiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode("bar"));
}
```

**Edit:** Bob's solution, from the comments.  Post your answer, Bob! Get credit for it. :-)

```
function start() {
    var myspan = document.getElementById("myspan");
    myspan.onclick = function() { alert ("hi"); };

    var mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
    var newcontent = document.createElement('div');
    newcontent.innerHTML = "bar";

    while (newcontent.firstChild) {
        mydiv.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there a substitute that can append an arbitrary blob of HTML?

Comment: newcontent= document.createElement('div'); newcontent.innerHTML= arbitrary_blob; while (newcontent.firstChild) mydiv.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild);

Comment: Nice, Bob! If you post that as a well-formatted answer, I'll select it.

Comment: @bobince — I've updated my answer with your technique, since you haven't posted it yet yourself. If you create your own answer, go ahead and roll mine back. :-)

Comment: @Ben: you don't need the call to newcontent.removeChild(). Bob's original comment was correct.

Comment: @crescentfresh — If you don't remove the child node from newcontent, `while (newcontent.firstChild)` loops forever. Try it.

Comment: Hmm… I take that back. It *shouldn't* loop — I have no idea what was going wrong the first time I tested it. :-/

Comment: Oh, one last thing, you'll want “var myspan”, “var newcontent” etc. to avoid accidentally spilling globals.

Comment: Heh. It's becoming apparent that my tendency to bash out quick & dirty example/prototype code doesn't serve me well on SO. :-)

Comment: `firstChild` didn't work as expected with me, but `firstElementChild` did.

Comment: @Omar How did it not work as expected? A construct with a loop like `const newContent = Object.assign(document.createElement("div"), { innerHTML: arbitraryBlob }); while(newContent.firstChild){ mydiv.appendChild(newcontent.firstChild); }` is expected to work. `newContent.firstChild` is either a Node or `null`. `appendChild` moves a Node — Nodes can’t exist at two places at once. So the loop eventually stops when `newContent.firstChild === null`; at this point, all child nodes of `newContent` have been moved to the target `mydiv` — without affecting any existing child nodes.

Answer (score 189):

Using [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) preserves event listeners, and [is supported by all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=insertadjacenthtml). It's a simple one-line replacement for `.innerHTML`.

```js
var html_to_insert = "<p>New paragraph</p>";

// with .innerHTML, destroys event listeners
document.getElementById('mydiv').innerHTML += html_to_insert;

// with .insertAdjacentHTML, preserves event listeners
document.getElementById('mydiv').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html_to_insert);
```

The `'beforeend'` argument specifies where in the element to insert the HTML content. Options are `'beforebegin'`, `'afterbegin'`, `'beforeend'`, and `'afterend'`. Their corresponding locations are:

```
<!-- beforebegin -->
<div id="mydiv">
  <!-- afterbegin -->
  <p>Existing content in #mydiv</p>
  <!-- beforeend -->
</div>
<!-- afterend -->
```

Comment: be careful Chrome / Edge complains about case sensitivity: i.e. `afterbegin` is not accepted `afterBegin` is!

Comment: @AK_ The [specification](//w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dom-element-insertadjacenthtml) guarantees that the string match is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 4):

Now, it is 2012, and jQuery has append and prepend functions that do exactly this, add content without effecting current content. Very useful.

Comment: [`.insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML) has been around since IE4

Comment: @Tynach yes it does, it's their JavaScript site that documents it the best: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Comment: @JordonBedwell, I honestly have no idea why I said what I did before. You're 100% right. I feel like at the time I briefly looked into it and couldn't find it, but... Honestly I have no excuse. Esailija even *links* to that page.

Comment: OP is not talking about jQuery

Comment: [jQuery meme fun](https://www.doxdesk.com/img/updates/20091116-so-large.gif)

Answer (score 3):

I created my markup to insert as a string since it's less code and easier to read than working with the fancy dom stuff.

Then I made it innerHTML of a temporary element just so I could take the one and only child of that element and attach to the body.

```
var html = '<div>';
html += 'Hello div!';
html += '</div>';

var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
tempElement.innerHTML = html;
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(tempElement.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a slight (but related) asside, if you use a javascript library such as jquery (v1.3) to do your dom manipulation you can make use of live events whereby you set up a handler like:

```
 $("#myspan").live("click", function(){
  alert('hi');
});
```

and it will be applied to that selector at all times during any kind of jquery manipulation.  For live events see: [docs.jquery.com/events/live](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/live) for jquery manipulation see: [docs.jquery.com/manipulation](http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation)

Comment: OP is not talking about jQuery

Answer (score 1):

There is another alternative: using `setAttribute` rather than adding an event listener. Like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Demo innerHTML and event listeners</title>
<style>
    div {
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 10px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <span>Click here.</span>
    </div>
    <script>
        document.querySelector('span').setAttribute("onclick","alert('Hi.')");
        document.querySelector('div').innerHTML += ' Added text.';
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it will work with es modules

Comment: @FLAW - I am sure it does.

Comment: *it* may, but I meant `setAttribute`. attributes are like strings afaik. so it basically means you write `<button onclick="myfun()"></button>` and if `myfun` is a function in a module, you can't reach it unless you make it global. piece of advice, don't make your surety become cheaper.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible if you bind events using tag attribute `onclick="sayHi()"` directly in template similar like your `<body onload="start()">` - this approach similar to frameworks angular/vue/react/etc. You can also use [`<template>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template) to operate on 'dynamic' html like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55937083/860099). It is not strict unobtrusive js however it is [acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54769527/860099) for small projects

```js
function start() {
  mydiv.innerHTML += "bar";
}

function sayHi() {
  alert("hi");
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <div id="mydiv" style="border: solid red 2px">
    <span id="myspan" onclick="sayHi()">foo</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Losing event handlers is, IMO, a bug in the way Javascript handles the DOM. To avoid this behavior, you can add the following:

```
function start () {
  myspan = document.getElementById("myspan");
  myspan.onclick = function() { alert ("hi"); };

  mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
  clickHandler = mydiv.onclick;  // add
  mydiv.innerHTML += "bar";
  mydiv.onclick = clickHandler;  // add
}
```

Comment: I don't consider this a bug. Replacing an element means you completely replace it. It should not inherit what was there before.

Comment: But I don't want to replace an element; I just want to append new ones to the parent.

Comment: If you were replacing the element, I would agree, @Diodeus. It's not the .innerHTML that has the event handler, but the .innerHtml's parent.

Comment: The innerHTML's owner does not lose handlers when its innerHTML is changed, only anything in its contents. And JavaScript doesn't know that you are only appending new children, since “x.innerHTML+= y” is only syntactical sugar for the string operation “x.innerHTML= x.innerHTML+y”.

Comment: You don't need to re-attach `mydiv.onclick`. Only the inner span's onclick is overridden by `innerHTML +=`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use an array and push elements into it and then insert the array subsequent values into the array dynamically.
Here is my code:

```
var namesArray = [];

function myclick(){
    var readhere = prompt ("Insert value");
    namesArray.push(readhere);
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML= namesArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Element#append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) can be used to insert elements at the end of another element. To insert HTML from a string, [`Range#createContextualFragment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/createContextualFragment) can be used.

```js
const mydiv = document.getElementById("mydiv");
mydiv.append(document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`
    <div>Some HTML here</div>
`));
```

Or to just append text:

```js
mydiv.append("some text"); // no need for document.createTextNode
```

If you don't need to insert HTML directly, consider using DOM methods to create the structure instead:

```js
mydiv.append(
    Object.assign(document.createElement('div'), 
              { textContent: 'some text', className: 'my-class' }),
    document.createElement('hr'),
    "some more text"
); 
// can append multiple elements (mixed with strings which are converted to text nodes)
```

On a related note, the corresponding [`Element#prepend`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) method can be used to insert elements at the start (before the first child) of an element.

Answer (score -1):

You could do it like this:

```
var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName('a'); 
var index_a = 0;
var uls = document.getElementsByTagName('UL'); 
window.onload=function()          {alert(anchors.length);};
for(var i=0 ; i<uls.length;  i++)
{
    lis = uls[i].getElementsByTagName('LI');
    for(var j=0 ;j<lis.length;j++)
    {
        var first = lis[j].innerHTML; 
        string = "<img src=\"http://g.etfv.co/" +  anchors[index_a++] + 
            "\"  width=\"32\" 
        height=\"32\" />   " + first;
        lis[j].innerHTML = string;
    }
}
```

Comment: How is this supposed to avoid losing event listeners?

Answer (score -1):

something.innerHTML += 'add whatever you want';

it worked for me. I added a button to an input text using this solution

Comment: It destroys all events.

Comment: how is it really a solution? it destroys all the events!!

Comment: and if you use web components it probably calls connected callbacks. essentially you re set the html, and all of the children are brand new elements. thus, no internal state (if they're not in the attributes) is preserved. also, it removes focus and deletes all the text you have inserted in lets say textarea. so, it should re render it all from your string. don't do it or avoid as much as possible.

Answer (score -1):

For any object array with header and data.`jsfiddle`

https://jsfiddle.net/AmrendraKumar/9ac75Lg0/2/

```
<table id="myTable" border='1|1'></table>

<script>
  const userObjectArray = [{
    name: "Ajay",
    age: 27,
    height: 5.10,
    address: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Vijay",
    age: 24,
    height: 5.10,
    address: "Bangalore"
  }, {
    name: "Dinesh",
    age: 27,
    height: 5.10,
    address: "Bangalore"
  }];
  const headers = Object.keys(userObjectArray[0]);
  var tr1 = document.createElement('tr');
  var htmlHeaderStr = '';
  for (let i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    htmlHeaderStr += "<th>" + headers[i] + "</th>"
  }
  tr1.innerHTML = htmlHeaderStr;
  document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(tr1);

  for (var j = 0; j < userObjectArray.length; j++) {
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    var htmlDataString = '';
    for (var k = 0; k < headers.length; k++) {
      htmlDataString += "<td>" + userObjectArray[j][headers[k]] + "</td>"
    }
    tr.innerHTML = htmlDataString;
    document.getElementById('myTable').appendChild(tr);
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score -7):

I'm a lazy programmer. I don't use DOM because it seems like extra typing. To me, the less code the better. Here's how I would add "bar" without replacing "foo":

```
function start(){
var innermyspan = document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML;
document.getElementById("myspan").innerHTML=innermyspan+"bar";
}
```

Comment: This question is asking how to do this without losing event handlers, so your answer is not relevant, and btw this is what += does, which is way shorter

Comment: It's hilarious that in this completely wrong answer that cites avoiding extra typing as a justification, about half the code is redundant.