# Deep cloning vs setting of innerHTML: what's faster?

Tags: javascript, dom, dhtml

I'm trying to figure out the most performant way of deep-cloning a DOM tree within the browser.

If I start out with

```
var div = document.getElementById("source");
var markup = div.innerHTML;
```

What will be faster,

```
var target = div.cloneNode(true);
```

or

```
var target = document.cloneNode(false);
target.innerHTML = markup;
```

I understand the browser platform may make a big difference here, so any information about how these compare in the real world would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get what you're looking for. You want to clone an element? `var target = div.cloneNode(true);` did just that. What does cloning have to do with `innerHTML`?

Comment: The specific results will depend on your browser, but I found two relevant tests at jsPerf [here](http://jsperf.com/clonenode-vs-createelement-performance/39) and [here](http://jsperf.com/innerclone/13).

Comment: [innerHTML destroys event listeners](http://stackoverflow.com/q/595808/1048572), don't use it.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Let's test!

I added the following code to a copy of StackOverflow's Questions page (removing existing scripts first, and running from scratch with one of the `timeit()`s uncommented each time around, three runs of 100 ops:

```
function timeit(f) {
    var start= new Date();
    for (var i=100; i-->0;) {
        f();
    }
    return new Date()-start;
}

var c= document.getElementById('content');
var clones= [];

//alert('cloneNode: '+timeit(function() {
//    clones.push(c.cloneNode(true));
//}))

//alert('innerHTML: '+timeit(function() {
//    var d= document.createElement('div');
//    d.innerHTML= c.innerHTML;
//    clones.push(d);
//}))
```

Here are the results running on a VirtualBox on a Core 2 Q9300:

```
IE7
cloneNode: 3238, 3235, 3187
innerHTML: 8442, 8468, 8552

Firefox3
cloneNode: 1294, 1315, 1289
innerHTML: 3593, 3636, 3580

Safari3
cloneNode: 207, 273, 237
innerHTML: 805, 818, 786

Chrome1
cloneNode: 329, 377, 426
innerHTML: 2327, 2536, 2865

Opera10
cloneNode: 801, 791, 771
innerHTML: 1852, 1732, 1672
```

So `cloneNode(true)` is much faster than copying `innerHTML`. Of course, it was always going to be; serialising a DOM to text and then re-parsing it from HTML is hard work. The reason DOM child operations are usually slow is that you're inserting/moving them one-by-one; all-at-once DOM operations like `cloneNode` don't have to do that.

Safari manages to do the `innerHTML` op amazingly quickly, but still not nearly as quickly as it does `cloneNode`. IE is, as expected, a dog.

So, auto -1s all round to everyone who said innerHTML would Obviously Be Faster without considering what the question was actually doing.

And yes, jQuery uses innerHTML to clone. Not because it's faster though — read the source:

```
// IE copies events bound via attachEvent when
// using cloneNode. Calling detachEvent on the
// clone will also remove the events from the orignal
// In order to get around this, we use innerHTML.
```

jQuery uses `Element.attachEvent()` to implement its own event system, so naturally, it needs to avoid that bug. If you don't need to, you can avoid the overhead.

**Off-topic aside:** Then again, I think holding jQuery up as the pinnacle of Best Practice may be a bit mistaken, especially given the next line:

```
html.replace(/ jQuery\d+="(?:\d+|null)"/g, "")
```

That's right — jQuery adds its own arbitrary attributes to HTML elements and then needs to get rid of them when it clones them (or otherwise gives access to their markup, such as through the `$().html()` method). This is ugly enough, but then it thinks the best way to do that is processing HTML using a regular expression, which is the kind of basic mistake you'd expect more from naïve 1-reputation SO questioners than the author of the Second Coming Best JS Framework Evar.

Hope you didn't have the string `jQuery1="2"` anywhere in your text content, 'cos if so you just mysteriously lost it. Thanks, jQuery! Thus ends the off-topic aside.

Comment: Excellent analisys. The only small nit is that I was looking to pre-serialize the source innerHTML once, not every time in the loop. But it still turns out slower.

Thanks.

Comment: Great answer Bobince. Just wondering, what *would* be the best way to drop off these extra attributes? Searching only within angle brackets from a whitelist of HTML elements, or making a DOM element and then using jQuery's `removeAttr()` on it? Perhaps it's a trade-off, it might be much faster at the expense of mangling anyone that uses that string. Although it is rare, there should be some sort of warning in the jQuery docs (I haven't found it if there is)

Comment: What I'd do would be to set a JS property for the ID instead of an HTML attribute. IE has a bug where properties are serialised as if they were attributes, but it only kicks in where the property value is a primitive datatype. Object-type properties aren't included in the `innerHTML`. So setting `elementnode.jQueryId45438= [1]` (an Array object) would allow jQuery to put its unique ID on the element without messing up the serialisation and requiring any post-`innerHTML` fixups.

Comment: (Actually personally I'd prefer not to be adding identifiers to element nodes at all, but jQuery relies on the ability quite heavily.)

Comment: Hey thanks for getting back to me. For what reason does jQuery add these extra attributes? I've noticed them in Firebug before.

Comment: It's essentially in order to decouple the element nodes from element data. This allows for data (including function/object references) to be associated with nodes without the risk of forming reference loops that leak memory in IE6-7. jQuery sets an ID attribute on the element, then looks up the same ID in a mapping (`jQuery.cache`) to get associated data. Event handling relies on a type of associated data, so pretty much every jQuery script is using this.

Comment: Wow! You really know your jQuery. Last time I looked at the source (a few years back) I didn't know much of what was going on!

Comment: "IE is, as expected, a dog." 

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm... interestingly, I just did a test in Firefox 3, and a deep clone seems to be about 3 times faster than going the innerHTML route.

I'm sure innerHTML is still faster than individual DOM operations, but at least for deep cloning, cloneNode(true) seems to be better optimized.