# Adding charts dynamically with flot

Tags: javascript, charts, flot

I'm running the following code. The button basically adds a chart into the html page. The problem I'm facing is: when I click on the button for the second time, the curve of the former chart fades away (though the labels don't), and I want it to stay. I've tried to debug and this happens when I modify the innerHTML property right at the beginning of the buttonClicked javascript function. Can anybody tell me why is this happening?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Configurando gráficos</title>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../scripts/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

var id = 0;

function requestGraph(placeholder) {
  $.ajax({url: "../requests/get_xml_oid.php?oid=1.3.6.1.2.1.2.2.1.10.65540&host=200.234.199.161", success: function(request){
        // Initialize dataToDraw to an empty array
        var dataToDraw = [];

        // The first tag is called ifInOctets      
        var ifInOctetsEl = request.getElementsByTagName("ifInOctets")[0];

        // Store the data element, to loop over the time-value pairs      
        var dataEl = ifInOctetsEl.getElementsByTagName("data");

        // For each data element, except the first one
        var i;
        for (i=1; i<dataEl.length; i++){
            // get the time-value pair
            var timeEl = dataEl[i].getElementsByTagName("time")[0];
            var valueEl = dataEl[i].getElementsByTagName("value")[0];
            var time = timeEl.textContent;
            var value = valueEl.textContent;

            // get the value of the former data element
            // Warning: the former value in the XML file is newer than the latter
            var formerValueEl = dataEl[i-1].getElementsByTagName("value")[0];
            var formerValue = formerValueEl.textContent;

            // push to the dataToDraw array
            dataToDraw.push( [parseInt(time)*1000, parseInt(formerValue) - parseInt(value)]);

        }

        // tell the chart that the x axis is a time variable
        var options = {
            xaxis: { mode: "time"}
        };

        // plot the chart and place it into the placeholder
        jQuery.plot(jQuery(placeholder), [dataToDraw], options);

      }});
}
function buttonClicked() {
    document.getElementById("body").innerHTML += "<div id=\"placeholder" + id + "\" style=\"width:600px;height:300px;\"></div>";
    requestGraph("#placeholder" + id);
    setInterval("requestGraph(\"#placeholder" + id + "\")",60000);
    id = id + 1;
}

</script>
</head>
<body id="body">
<button type="button" onClick="buttonClicked()">Click Me!</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fun), assigning to innerHTML destroys child elements. It's not clear to me that this is exactly what you're seeing, but perhaps using `document.createElement` as suggested in the similar question will work for you as well.