# How to append text to a div element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I’m using AJAX to append data to a `<div>` element, where I fill the `<div>` from JavaScript. How can I append new data to the `<div>` without losing the previous data found in it?

Comment: $(div).append(data);

Comment: Is this the "data" attribute, or the innerHTML you're speaking about?

Comment: @jimy thats jquery, no need to use that for such a trivial thing

Comment: @Neal sure, but he's using AJAX too, so jQuery is definitely a good idea!

Comment: @Alnitak, but how do you know the OP is using jQuery for anything?

Comment: @Neal I don't - I said if he's doing AJAX as well that he _should_ use jQuery. Then he'll get all this DOM stuff for free, too!

Comment: @Alnitak, jQuery is not the **only** ajax solution

Comment: mblenton's answer shows a pure javascript version of append, almost just as simple.

Answer (score 701, accepted):

Try this:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML += 'Extra stuff';
```

Comment: Danger, Will Robinson! This adds *HTML*, not text. If your Extra Stuff is provided by the user, you've just introduced a security vulnerabilty. Better to use @Chandu's answer below.

Comment: Refering to the reply of @DavidGiven is it really a security problem? if it is what could be safe?

Comment: Yes, it's an [XSS vulnerability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting). You're far better off creating a text node with the content instead, as describe in the answer below.

Comment: This also woudn’t work in case `div` contains elements with event listeners or inputs with user-entered text. I recommend the [answer by Chandu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677825/4642212).

Comment: This is not recommended, see [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/595808/1048572)

Comment: I tried this solution with document.getElementsByClassName instead of getElementByID. With ID it works, but with ClassName it doesn't. Why is this?

Comment: Because classname returns you a list whereas ID returns only one

Comment: what if the element has a class with name on it. Instead of getElementById can we use classname?

Comment: Yes, I definitely do not recommend this as this will destroy state of any checkboxes, event listeners.

Comment: As others have said, do not do this ! Append a child TextNode, see @Chandu’s answer.

Comment: Doing this will destroy event listeners as stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677950/4284627).

Comment: How do you add a space to the div?

Comment: This should be mentioned from the comment below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34551817/6058482

Comment: Although this works for most cases, a word of warning - it is way slower than actually appending new elements that you create for every bit you want to add to it, and the slowdown will be noticeable if you e.g. use this as some log output where you just append text this way. It recreates the whole dom for the component for every bit you add!

Comment: `innerHTML` is read/write meaning it will destroy everything in element. Try to avoid it.

Answer (score 408):

Using appendChild:

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("<ID_OF_THE_DIV>");
var content = document.createTextNode("<YOUR_CONTENT>");
theDiv.appendChild(content);
```

Using innerHTML:
This approach will remove all the listeners to the existing elements as mentioned by @BiAiB. So use caution if you are planning to use this version.

```
var theDiv = document.getElementById("<ID_OF_THE_DIV>");
theDiv.innerHTML += "<YOUR_CONTENT>";
```

Comment: I use this method with my "contenteditable" element with angularjs binding, and everything work correctly!

Comment: Should be the accepted answer indeed. Not only a beautiful way, but innerHTML will rebuild the DOM, and that is just not a good solution. Use appendChild().

Comment: This is better, but `createTextNode` won't work if you are loading HTML. If you wanted to add list items, for example, this wouldn't work. That is pretty limiting.

Comment: what if we want to change the text of same appended text node in the next event ?

Comment: This is much easier with the [more recent](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/append#browser_compatibility) [`theDiv.append("The additional content.")`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

Comment: @Jake If HTML needs to be inserted instead of plain text, then don’t use `createTextNode`. There are several other methods for DOM manipulation related to this, e.g. [`insertAdjacentHTML`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [`insertAdjacentElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement), etc. Can’t call it “limiting” if you’re using the wrong tools. The question, though, could be clearer as to what is meant by “data”.

Comment: The first solution with `createTextNode` solved an issue I had adding a text in a label. When I was using `innerText`,  the input inside the label was replaced

Comment: Hello @wrongite ! I am currently studying Angular, JavaScript, and your comment got my attention... Can you ellaborate a little bit on how do you use AngularJS binding and this method? You can send me a documentation link or something similar, so I can take some readings at it and understand this logic a little better... Thank you.

Answer (score 142):

Beware of `innerHTML`, you sort of *lose* something when you use it:

```
theDiv.innerHTML += 'content';
```

Is equivalent to:

```
theDiv.innerHTML = theDiv.innerHTML + 'content';
```

Which will destroy all nodes inside your `div` and recreate new ones. **All references and listeners to elements inside it will be lost**.

If you need to keep them (when you have attached a click handler, for example), you have to append the new contents with the DOM functions(appendChild,insertAfter,insertBefore):

```
var newNode = document.createElement('div');
newNode.innerHTML = data;
theDiv.appendChild(newNode);
```

Comment: yes but this will cause there to be an **extra** div inside the parent div which is not needed and might mess up some css styles

Comment: @Neal this is just a example way to use appendChild. the point is not here.

Comment: The correct way to do the `appendChild` was done by @Cybernate

Comment: @Neal no it's not. It's neither correct or incorrect. It just depends on what the OP needs to append: text, html code or something else.

Comment: @Neal this is a perfectly good way of appending the data, and is more versatile than `document.createTextNode()`.

Answer (score 74):

If you want to do it **fast** and don't want to lose references and listeners use: **.insertAdjacentHTML()**;

"It **does not reparse the element** it is being used on and thus **it does not corrupt the existing elements** inside the element. This, and avoiding the extra step of serialization make it **much faster** than direct innerHTML manipulation."

Supported on all mainline browsers (IE6+, FF8+,All Others and Mobile): http://caniuse.com/#feat=insertadjacenthtml

Example from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

```
// <div id="one">one</div>
var d1 = document.getElementById('one');
d1.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', '<div id="two">two</div>');

// At this point, the new structure is:
// <div id="one">one</div><div id="two">two</div>
```

Comment: are there any considerations, constraints, etc. when using this method?

Comment: Awesome compatibility: better solution!

Comment: There is also `insertAdjacentElement()` and `insertAdjacentText()`.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertadjacenthtml.asp

Comment: This method is best solution!

Answer (score 17):

If you are using jQuery you can use `$('#mydiv').append('html content')` and it will keep the existing content.

http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 11):

IE9+ (Vista+) solution, without creating new text nodes:

```
var div = document.getElementById("divID");
div.textContent += data + " ";
```

However, this didn't quite do the trick for me since I needed a new line after each message, so my DIV turned into a styled UL with this code:

```
var li = document.createElement("li");
var text = document.createTextNode(data);
li.appendChild(text);
ul.appendChild(li);
```

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent :

> Differences from innerHTML
>
> innerHTML returns the HTML as its name indicates. Quite often, in order to retrieve or write text within an element, people use innerHTML. textContent should be used instead. Because the text is not parsed as HTML, it's likely to have better performance. Moreover, this avoids an XSS attack vector.

Answer (score 8):

Even this will work:

```
var div = document.getElementById('divID');

div.innerHTML += 'Text to append';
```

Answer (score 7):

An option that I think is better than any of the ones mentioned so far is [`Element.insertAdjacentText()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText).

```js
// Example listener on a child element
// Included in this snippet to show that the listener does not get corrupted
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', () => {
  console.log('click');
});

// to actually insert the text:
document.querySelector('div').insertAdjacentText('beforeend', 'more text');
```

```html
<div>
  <button>click</button>
</div>
```

Advantages to this approach include:

- Does not modify the existing nodes in the DOM; does not [corrupt event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/595808)
- Inserts *text*, not HTML (Best to only use `.insertAdjacentHTML` when deliberately inserting HTML - using it unnecessarily is less semantically appropriate and can increase the risk of XSS)
- Flexible; the first argument to `.insertAdjacentText` may be `beforebegin`, `beforeend`, `afterbegin`, `afterend`, depending on where you'd like the text to be inserted

Comment: *Question*: Why not [**`append()/prepend()`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78015777/5951529)? What disadvantages of these methods are known to you? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can use jQuery. which make it very simple.

just download the jQuery file add jQuery into your HTML 
or you can user online link:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and try this:

```
 $("#divID").append(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The following method is less general than others however it's great when you are sure that your last child node of the div is already a text node. In this way you won't create a new text node using `appendData` [MDN Reference AppendData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CharacterData)

```
let mydiv = document.getElementById("divId");
let lastChild = mydiv.lastChild;

if(lastChild && lastChild.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE ) //test if there is at least a node and the last is a text node
   lastChild.appendData("YOUR TEXT CONTENT");
```

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. My choice

[**Unicorn**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn) code style checker recommends using Vanilla JS methods [**`append()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append) and [**`prepend()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/prepend) instead of methods [**`insertAdjacentElement()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement) and [**`insertAdjacentText()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentText).

#### 2. Demonstration

[**Live demonstration on LiveCodes**](https://v24.livecodes.io/?x=id/rma2g9qw5qa):

```coffee
kiraGoddessDiv = document.createElement("div")
kiraGoddessDiv.textContent = "is"
kiraGoddessDiv.prepend("Kira ")
kiraGoddessDiv.append(" Goddess!")
console.log(kiraGoddessDiv.textContent)
```

Result in console:

```
Kira is Goddess!
```

#### 3. Advantages

##### 3.1. “InnerHTML” disadvantages

In the article “[**Why InnerHTML Is a Bad Idea and How to Avoid It?**](https://www.dhairyashah.dev/posts/why-innerhtml-is-a-bad-idea-and-how-to-avoid-it/)” software engineer Dhairya Shah lists the inherent disadvantages of `innerHTML`:

1. Security risk
2. Slow process
3. Can break the document
4. Appending is not supported
5. Content is replaced everywhere

##### 3.2. Advantages over “insertAdjacentElement()” and “insertAdjacentText()”

Description of the Unicorn [**`prefer-modern-dom-apis` rule**](https://github.com/sindresorhus/eslint-plugin-unicorn/blob/main/docs/rules/prefer-modern-dom-apis.md), why prefer one of `.after()`, `.append()`, `.before()` or `.prepend()` over `insertAdjacentElement()` and `insertAdjacentText()`:

> There are some advantages of using the newer DOM APIs, like:
>
> 1. Traversing to the parent node is not necessary.
> 2. Appending multiple nodes at once.
> 3. Both [**`DOMString`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString) and [**DOM node objects**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) can be manipulated.

#### 4. Browser compatibility

1. [**Method `append()` on caniuse.com**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_append):

   [image: append() method on CanIUse]
2. [**Method `prepend()` on caniuse.com**](https://caniuse.com/mdn-api_element_prepend):

   [image: prepend() method on CanIUse]

Chrome, Firefox, Opera and Safari supports `append()` and `prepend()` since 2016, Edge — since 2018.

#### 5. Security

##### 5.1. “append()” and “prepend()” safety

I haven’t found any information that using `append()` and `prepend()` entails any security problems.

##### 5.2. “InnerHTML” and “insertAdjacentText()” safety

Dhairya Shah in the article mentioned above wrote:

> The website can become very vulnerable if innerHTML is used constantly. For instance, using it for input fields can cause DOM manipulation, and attackers can use cross-site scripting (XSS) to insert harmful scripts and steal the private and sensitive data stored in session cookies.
>
> The idea behind an [**XSS attack**](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/xss/) with innerHTML is that malicious code is injected into your site and then executed. This is possible because innerHTML renders complete markup rather than just text.

Stack Overflow user @CertainPerformance with a reputation of more than 362 thousand points wrote that “[**In terms of security, `insertAdjacentHTML` is not really better than `innerHTML`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68240296/5951529)”

##### 5.3. no-unsanitized

Mozilla’s developers have written an ESLint plugin [**no-unsanitized**](https://github.com/mozilla/eslint-plugin-no-unsanitized) that warns users about unsafe use of `innerHTML`, `insertAdjacentHTML()` and alike. Examples of not allowed practices from the [**plugin documentation**](https://github.com/mozilla/eslint-plugin-no-unsanitized#examples):

```js
foo.innerHTML = input.value;
bar.innerHTML = "<a href='"+url+"'>About</a>";
```

Examples of allowed practices:

```js
foo.innerHTML = 5;
bar.innerHTML = "<a href='/about.html'>About</a>";
bar.innerHTML = escapeHTML`<a href='${url}'>About</a>`;
```

#### 6. Relevance of the answer

This answer is relevant as of February 2024. In the future, data of my answer may be obsolete.

Answer (score -1):

**java script**

```
document.getElementById("divID").html("this text will be added to div");
```

**jquery**

```
$("#divID").html("this text will be added to div");
```

Use `.html()` without any arguments to see that you have entered.
You can use the browser console to quickly test these functions before using them in your code.

Comment: This is a copy of the accepted answer an one other.  Why?

Comment: innerHtml and html() worked differently on my project. innerHtml did nothing in one scenario.
So added it, in case its the same for anyone else.

Comment: Neither an `innerHtml` nor an `html` property exists anywhere on the prototype chain of [`HTMLElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement)s. The jQuery alternative has all the drawbacks of the (unfortunately) [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677816/4642212), _and_ it requires an unnecessary dependency.

Answer (score -2):

Why not just use setAttribute ?

```
thisDiv.setAttribute('attrName','data you wish to append');
```

Then you can get this data by :

```
thisDiv.attrName;
```

Comment: Because that has nothing to do with the question?