# creating multiple vertical lines in HTML using loops

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm new to JS and would like to create 10 vertical lines in my webpage. I have written my HTML code as

```
  <div id="verticle-line"></div>
```

and in my CSS I have

```
#verticle-line {
width: 1px;
min-height: 400px;
background: red;  
margin:15px;  
float:left
}
```

How Can I create 10 such lines in my webpage using JavaScript?

Comment: check this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304453/javascript-append-html-to-container-element-without-innerhtml

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37049408/creating-multiple-vertical-lines-in-html-using-loops#answer-37049747

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create a div using loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398522/create-a-div-using-loop)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do this but the easiest would probably be this:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  document.write('<div class="verticle-line"></div>');
}
```

Use a for loop to write 10 divs on your page. I also changed id to class, because you should not have more than one element with the same id on your page. Make sure you change your CSS to match a class.

Answer (score 3):

See this -

```js
for(x=0; x<9;x++) {
    var vertical = document.createElement('div');
    vertical.className = "verticle-line";
    document.getElementById('wrapper').appendChild(vertical);
}
```

```css
.verticle-line {
  width: 1px;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin: 15px;
  float: left
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="verticle-line"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You shouldn't have multiple elements with the same class. It would better be changed to class

Comment: In that case, we can use vertical.className = "verticle-line"; instead of vertical.id = "verticle-line"; Will update the snippet anyway

Comment: @Jinu Kurian is there a way to create some horizontal lines over vertical ones so that I get a graph-like drawing.