# common class - css margin-top is not working

Tags: html, css

hello my common class but margin-top or margin-bottom is not working..
 thank you

```css
.cl
{

 position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
 
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #6686a7;
    margin-top:150px
 

}
```

```html
 
<div id="1" class="cl"></div>
<div id="2" class="cl"></div>
<div id="3" class="cl"></div>
<div id="4" class="cl"></div>
......
```

Comment: Your margins are working fine but are meaningless when you set the position to absolute.

Comment: you defined margin-top twice

Comment: hi    margin: 3em 0 1em 3.6em; I removed but again is not working

Comment: when you use ```margin``` with position ```absolute```, you need to know your element will ignore the margin, try to use ```top:150px```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove 'position: absolute;' The margin doesn't work with 'position:absolute'

Use below code

```
.cl{
display: inline-block; 
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border-radius: 4px;
background: #6686a7;
margin-top:150px}
```

Answer (score 0):

You know that both elements overlap each other, do you? So they're in the very same position. Also you're defining margin-top and margin-bottom with just margin. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want vertical div's

example 
div1
margin-top 10
div2
margin-top 10

Comment: Okay you can do it like this: `<div id="first" class="same cl">test</div>
<div id="second" class="same c2">test2</div> .same {
     position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 210px;
    height: 210px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #6686a7;
} .c1 { 
  margin-top:100px; 
}
.c2 { 
  margin-top:400px; 
} ` 

What happens in this code is that you define a standard class that has attribute and values which should be the same in both elements. Classes c1 and c2 define what makes the difference between both elements.

Comment: hi thank you but is I tried it..my problem  I have multiple div's
I can't create class c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6..beacuse I'm dynamically creating I
and I am giving a dynamic id

sample 
var pageID = page.val()
id="dynamic_"+pageID"

Comment: Have you thought about adding the class to the element through a for-loop? In this case you would also be able to do c1 .. cn and creating a new div-element with an id whichs value (id="iterator") equals the size of the itarator (which is defined as variable "i" in a loop). This element with id = iterator could then get a class with "c"+i. Check this link here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398522/create-a-div-using-loop Are you using JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to include margin-top in your CSS (which should also have a semi-colon at the end of the line if you did need it) when you've already declared top and bottom margins prior to that.  Your CSS is valid otherwise.  Side note: Your divs overlap each other based on the absolute positioning.  Not sure if that's something you intended.

Comment: hi margin: 3em 0 1em 3.6em; I removed but again is not working