# Why does my nested for loop for creatDocumentFragment run the outside for loop only once?

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to run this loop for the purpose of creating a specific amount of columns and add squares to each column. The goal was to do this all in one loop but my loop will run once, successfully, then quit.

```
function gridBuilder(columns,rows) {
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
     var column = document.createElement('div');
     column.id = 'card-column-'+i;
     for (i = 1; i <= rows; i++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.id = 'card-'+i;
        row.className = 'card';
        column.appendChild(row);
     }
     column.className = 'card-column';
     toAdd.appendChild(column);
  }

  document.getElementById('card-container').appendChild(toAdd);
}
```

Understanding you are missing the HTML/CSS (it's a lot). Why is it that when I run `gridBuilder(5,4);` it creates only 1 column with 4 Squares, like below.

```
<div id="card-container">

          <div id="card-column-1" class="card-column">
              <div id="card-1" class="card"></div>
              <div id="card-2" class="card"></div>
              <div id="card-3" class="card"></div>
              <div id="card-4" class="card"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Note:** Chrome console gives no errors. I got most of this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11398522/create-a-div-using-loop). Is it not possible to run a nested for loop like this for some reason?

Comment: Can you create plunker for this code?

Comment: I don't know what plunker is, but I just figured it out... Will post an answer so other noobs can see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid using a fragment and just append it to `#card-container`.

You should also add a `var` in the for loops to avoid [global variables](https://www.google.ca/search?q=js+avoid+global+variables&rlz=1C1JZAP_enCA709CA709&oq=js+why+avoid+&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.3047j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

And yes, as you said, you can't use the same variable in both for loops. Great job finding it yourself!

```
function gridBuilder(columns, rows) {
  container = document.getElementById('card-container');
  for (var i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
    var column = document.createElement('div');
    column.id = 'card-column-' + i;
    for (var j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
      var row = document.createElement('div');
      row.id = 'card-' + j;
      row.className = 'card';
      column.appendChild(row);
    }
    column.className = 'card-column';
    container.appendChild(column);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would one want to avoid the use of fragment? I was under the (very possibly incorrect) understanding that it was better for performance to use a fragment for this type of operation.

Thank you!

Comment: @MattWeber I think that's only "when it is used to insert a *set of elements* in **multiple places**". [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14203196/does-using-a-document-fragment-really-improve-performance). Check out [this performance test](https://jsperf.com/fragment-vs-just-append).

Comment: @MattWeber I think you're right! Depending on how's your computer is feeling, it's sometimes faster than other times.

Answer (score 1):

When running a nested for loop you cannot use the same variable in both for loop parameters. In this case, I used `i` twice. I changed the second loop to use `j` and now it works... will just leave this here for others.

```
function gridBuilder(columns,rows) {
  var toAdd = document.createDocumentFragment();
  for (i = 1; i <= columns; i++) {
     var column = document.createElement('div');
     column.id = 'card-column-'+i;
     for (j = 1; j <= rows; j++) {
        var row = document.createElement('div');
        row.id = 'card-'+j;
        row.className = 'card';
        column.appendChild(row);
     }
     column.className = 'card-column';
     toAdd.appendChild(column);
  }
```