# Insert text after an <img> tag

Tags: javascript, html

I try to insert text after an `<img>` tag using javascript.

```
<div id="candy"><img src="candy.png" /> Insert text here!</div>
```

If I use `document.getElementById('candy').innerHTML = "test";` the image disappears.

Can you help me?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/

Comment: He did not specify that he wanted to use jQuery.

Comment: @Allendar OP hasn't mentioned using any framework

Answer (score 6):

That's because you're replacing the `innerHTML` with the text `test`. You're not appending the text.

Try:

```
var div = document.getElementById('candy');
div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + 'test';
```

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript).

Comment: Applying this to the OP's example markup the result will be `Insert text here!test` so it will work only once, and only if there isn't any text in the div beforehand.

Comment: I assumed that the text: `Insert text here!` would be nonexistent, and then the JS would you know, insert the text there :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, the img tag is part of the HTML inside the div, and if you replace the div's HTML you rewrite the img tag as well.

Perhaps you wanted something like this instead:

```
<div><img src="candy.png" /> <span id="candy">Insert text here!</span></div>
```

Comment: Is there something more "properly", I mean a function like `lastChild` ?

Comment: Sure, `var children = document.getElementById('candy').childNodes; var lastChild = children[ children.length - 1 ];` but it's not any more "proper" than a named span.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
var div = document.getElementById('candy');
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'test');
```

Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score -4):

That is because you javascript changes the html inside the `<img>` tag to test. This doesn't work as `<img />` is a self-closing tag.

I believe you could you jQuery to do what you are trying to however.