# Javascript equivalent to JQuery append STYLE tag to head

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, iframe, append

The last line of my code is jquery. It works, but I'm trying to find the pure-javascript equivalent

jQuery

```
var previewFrame = document.getElementById('my_iframe'),
    preview =  previewFrame.contentDocument ||  previewFrame.contentWindow.document;

    preview.open();
    preview.close();

    style = document.createElement( 'style' ); 
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.id = 'xmain_css1';
    $('#my_iframe').contents().find('head').append(style);
```

.

This is the closest I could come up with for the LAST LINE (Doesn't work):

```
preview.head.appendChild(style);
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: try: preview.head.innerHTML += style; (untested)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append data to div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

Comment: Seems to work just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/XhZLD/4/, is the iFrame showing a page from the same domain.

Comment: Yes. Both of your codes work well. I think something is messed up in my main project as it is not working - but I too created a fiddle with your code and it works great. I'll have to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Thanks guys!

Comment: @Gianps. No. Appending to elements in an iframe is different than appending to a div.

Comment: @adeneo. I'm one of the million people who are attempting to make their own jsfiddle - so the iframe will custom html/css/js that the user types into each textarea