# Create new praragraph and put variable value in it - Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, stopwatch

I'm trying to make a stopwatch in Javascript and HTML. I got all the buttons and the stopwatch itself working but there is just one thing I can't understand how to do. When I press the lap button I wan't to print the laptime in a new paragraph in my HTML document.

So if I press the lap button I want the time to show up in a list under and if I press it again I want it to show up under the last time and so on.
But I can't just understand how to do.

I'm glad for all the help!

//Villevillekulla

Comment: show us your code! Best put it on jsfiddle.

Comment: No, it's *essential* (and therefore 'best') to *show code here in the question*; live demos are a bonus, and do help, but they are not the 'best' by any stretch.

Comment: Or also possibly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript, or a million other questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some code would be helpful, but I imagine you'll want something close to this:

```js
var laptime_val = '2:23';

var laptime_el = document.createElement('p');
document.body.appendChild(laptime_el);

laptime_el.innerHTML = laptime_val;
```

Comment: @Villevillekulla remember to select the answer that worked for your so the submitter is awarded the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check this [stopwatch](http://jsfiddle.net/0pt7dgv5/).

Html:

```
<button id="lap">Lap</button>
<div id="screen"></div>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var time = 0;
    var timer;

    $('#lap').click(function(){
        if (!timer){
            timer = setInterval(function(){
                time+=0.010;
                $("#screen p:last").text(time.toFixed(2));
            },10);
        }
        $("#screen").append('<p>'+time+'</p>');

    });
});
```