# How to call a JavaScript function that displays a block of code with custom message?

Tags: javascript, html

What I want is to call the `showPopup('text goes here');` function and the below block of code to be shown with my text in it.

How can I achieve this?

```
function showPopup(data) {

}


    <a class="fragment" href="#">
<span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>
  <div class="content">
    // I WANT TO PUT MY TEXT HERE
  </div>
    </a>
```

Comment: You need to append the HTML into the body and then style it with CSS. You could put some timeout on it so the message dissappears after some period.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to append data to div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JSFiddle example:** http://jsfiddle.net/tb5musm6/

```
function showPopup(data) {
    var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('content');
    elem[0].innerHTML = data;
}

showPopup('asdf');
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return an array of elements with the given classname

`innerHTML` variable holds all content between tags

Comment: Hi, can you please tell me how to have the div hidden and appeared only when the function is called ?

Comment: If you're working with the same element, set `.content{ display:none }` in css. Then add `elem[0].style.display='initial';` to the end of the js function (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tb5musm6/1/)

Comment: Thank you I changed it a bit to meet my requirements. Maybe it is a quick and dirty fix though.. jsfiddle.net/tb5musm6/2

Comment: I have a problem after adding your addition.. if you click on the X button it removes the whole page http://jsfiddle.net/ntqr3ubx/ but didn't happen in here http://jsfiddle.net/xftr5/749/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77725/discussion-between-seth-mcclaine-and-xalloumokkelos).

Comment: No, the first link is my attempt after including your function, and the second link is the example that i took for the modal window. if you click X on the modal window of the second link, the window will be hidden. In the first link, the window will be hidden but also the whole page content

Answer (score -1):

Add an id to you div so you can find it easier.

Then, use `innerHTML` to modify the content of the div.

```
<a class="fragment" href="#">
    <span id='close' onclick='this.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode.parentNode); return false;'>x</span>
    <div class="content" id="content">
    // I WANT TO PUT MY TEXT HERE
    </div>
</a>

<script>
function showPopup(data) {
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML(data);
}

showPopup('my text');
</script>
```

Comment: Yeah, it's to make it easier.
`getElementsByClassName('content')[0]` would work too

Comment: It's becoming standard to avoid utilizing id since they are expected to be unique which can be difficult to maintain in larger applications

Comment: Just like `getElementsByClassName('content')[0]` would not work if there is another `class="content"` before in the code.

Comment: no... it would still work, it just wouldn't give you results that you expect

Comment: There is a difference between programatic errors and logical errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77716/discussion-between-heru-luin-and-seth-mcclaine).