# How to add date to all items having class date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have 5 `<p class ='date'></p>` elements to all of which I want to append a current date, how can I accomplish this using JavaScript.

Comment: What - using the same id 5 times??? id should be unique, try to find a common class that you only assign to these `<p>`s. And then add the formatted date like suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript

Comment: ID's should always be unique... And if you want to Change them to the current date, take the class Attribute

Comment: Thank you for noticing that corrected it, I just want to learn a the way to append elements to all divs having same class

Answer (score 0):

```
var newDate = new Date().toISOString(); // Or whatever date you need
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("date");
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].textContent += newDate;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you said javascript not jquery ! so this way :

```html
<p class ='date'></p>
<p class ='date'></p>
<p class ='date'></p>
<p class ='date'></p>
<p class ='date'></p>
<p>i don't have the class "date"</p>
<script>
 var today="2015/x/x";//assume you have the date!
 var paras=document.getElementsByClassName("date");
 for(i=0;i<paras.length;i++)
 {
   paras[i].textContent+=today;
 }
 
</script>
```

*** i corrected my answer !