# Javascript createElement, add html element and simple text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create this html block in javascript:

```
<label>
  <input name="{{ $amenity->name }}" type="checkbox" class="minimal">
  text
</label>
```

I have:

```
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
var label_input = document.createElement("label");
label_input.innerHTML = value.name;
label_input.appendChild(checkBox);
```

But the result is

```
<label>
  text
  <input name="{{ $amenity->name }}" type="checkbox" class="minimal">
</label>
```

and I tried to add the checkbox first and then the text but no success.

Comment: It’s probably a duplicate of [How to append data to div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5677799/4642212) (see the [answer by Chandu](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5677825/4642212)).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using [`document.createTextNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createTextNode) for appending text content to the end of the label.

```
var checkBox = document.createElement("input");
var label_input = document.createElement("label");
label_input.appendChild(checkBox);
label_input.appendChild(document.createTextNode(value.name));
```