# Create multiple innerHTML elements with multiple function declaration

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop

I have the following code which I want to create the following links in the HTML if you have opened the `http://domain.com/10` URL:

```
<a href="http://domain.com/5">5</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/6">6</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/7">7</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/8">8</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/9">9</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/10">10</a> // --> You have opened this URL!
<a href="http://domain.com/11">11</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/12">12</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/13">13</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/14">14</a>
<a href="http://domain.com/15">15</a>
```

Here is the code:

```
(function() {
  function pagination(number) {
    var url = window.location.href;
    var page = parseInt(url.match(/[^/]+$/));
    var link = '<a href="' + url.replace(/[^/]+$/, '') + (page + number) + '">' + (page + number) + '</a>';
    document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML = link;
    console.log(link);
  };
  for (var i=-5; i<6; i++) {
    pagination(i);
  };
})();
```

This code has some problems:

- `console.log(link);` will print all of the necessary lines to the console without any problem, but `.innerHTML` is only appending the last element to the DOM.
- Somehow I want to hide -5, -4, -3, -2, -1 when you standing at 0 URL.

Comment: `innerHTML` replace the current code by the new one

Comment: you should use `div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + link;`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append data to div using javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assigning something to `innerHTML` replaces entire element contents with HTML contents. You should append `innerHTML` instead:

```
document.getElementById('pagination').innerHTML += link;
```

To prevent outputting -5, -4, -3, -2, -1 indices, you should probably just check if the `number` argument is equal to one of these values, e.g.:

```
function pagination(number) {
    if (number > -6 && number < 0) {
        return;
    }
    //
};
```

Comment: For completition: after `var page = parseInt(url.match(/[^/]+$/));` you should add an `if ((page + number)>0){`

Comment: @Marat Tanalin Thank You for your answer!