# Display application name on keycloak login page

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I have two applications `App1` and `App2` which interacts with `keycloak` for authentication of users.

I want to display application name on `keycloak` login page.

Eg.: if the user is logging into `App1`, the `keycloak` login page should display "Log in to App1".
Same should happen for `App2` also.

How can this be achieved.?

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a custom login theme, you can access the client name or the client ID in your Freemarker templates as `${client.name}` or `${client.clientId}` respectively. The client name is probably the best fit for this case: just set it to the name of the app through the Keycloak admin console.

The available Freemarker variables are not well documented unfortunately. You can look through Keycloak's source code (the [FreemarkerLoginFormsProvider](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/blob/11.0.3/services/src/main/java/org/keycloak/forms/login/freemarker/FreeMarkerLoginFormsProvider.java) class in particular) to find what other variables are made available. Look for calls to `attributes.put`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep both in the same realm, just add the javascript code to a [custom theme login page](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes). The `client_id` is passed as a request parameter to the login page. For instance:

```js
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
    if (!url) url = window.location.href;
    name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
    var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
        results = regex.exec(url);
    if (!results) return null;
    if (!results[2]) return '';
    return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(window).load(function(){ 
    var clientName = getParameterByName('client_id');
    var title = document.getElementById('title');
    title.innerHTML += clientName;
});
```

**See also:**

- [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)
- [How to append data to div using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript)
- [JavaScript that executes after page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/807878/javascript-that-executes-after-page-load)

Answer (score 1):

to apply different themes to different clientIds in same realm we can apply theme at client id from keycloak config itself :

[image: 1]

Answer (score -2):

My guess: use two different realms (`App1, App2`) and create customized Keycloak theme for each realm - https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_development/index.html#_themes

Comment: I also thought of this. But i am trying to do it in the same realm.

Comment: Found the solution, there is an attribute `Name` in `Client` in admin>client>your client, which is accessible on client layer by the ${client.name}. This solved my purpose.

Comment: What if I have 20 clients, should I replicate my realm 20 times?

Comment: Read my comment..the second one.

Comment: Original question was about app name, not about client name. So it depends what do you want to display in the UI.