# How to present information about the app I'm logging into via keycloak?

Tags: single-sign-on, keycloak

I have a Keycloak installation that provides single-sign-on for different webapps the teams in my company have created to our customers. I would like the login dialog present some more information about the app they are going to login to.

So for example, like this:

```
*LOGIN at COMPANY*

   ICON   name of webapp
          "Cool webapp lets you do all your web stuff!"

username: ______________________ 
password: ______________________ 

[Login]
```

The customers are not allowed to know, which apps are all existing. I could create a mask in every app, but I want to have a standard look and feel managed via keycloak theme. Is there any functionaly so that I can lookup a mini template per app and add it to my login form?

Comment: I guess you've already created a team and you're interested in having all your apps in the same realm. One easy workaround would be to add some JS code to the template and perform the logic of setting the icon and app description depending on the app's client name. Take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50837542/1199132

Comment: Hmm good idea, but that would expose all the apps that exist, which I don't want but didnt say. I'll add it to the question XD

Comment: It might be, depending on how you program your client js code. Anyway, that shouldn't cause a security issue, given that all the clients being referenced there are public and require a login process.