# I want to display a picture

Tags: javascript, dom

```js
function rpsGame() {
  var textAnswer = document.createTextNode('You chose a paper');
  document.getElementById('this').appendChild("textAnswer");
}
```

```html
<img id="paper" src="./paper.jpg" height=150 width=150 onclick="rpsGame()"></div>
<div class="answer">
  <div id="this"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

The error I get is:

> Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

I want it to show the text on the div called this.

Comment: The error message is quite clear. You're passing a string to `appendChild`, not the expected (text) node.

Comment: Hey SirMatope, duplicate question just here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-data-to-div-using-javascript

hope it will help you

Comment: Typo: Variable names shouldn't have quotes around them.