# Overriding console.log, etc to display inside HTML view

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, console.log

So, I'm working on a project in which the actual production environment has access to APIs that I can't get except by loading the page inside the production environment (they are using `angular.$window.external`), but loading the page inside production means I can't access developer tools, console, etc. because it runs in an in-application browser instance. So I am trying to output all console log/etc statements into a div in my document to try to troubleshoot when my API calls do not work as expected.

I got it sort of working, but it misses some things and I am not sure why.

The code I am including as `consoledebug.js`:

```
// Code adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/5677825/12869266
// Include consoledebug.js at the end of a file, and create a div with
// the id "logs" in your html file where you want output.

var logDiv = document.getElementById('logs')

var addToLogDiv = function (type, text) {
  var node = document.createElement('p')
  node.className = type
  var content = document.createTextNode(type + ': ' + text)
  node.appendChild(content)
  logDiv.appendChild(node)
}

// define a new console
var console = (function (oldCons) {
  return {
    log: function (text) {
      oldCons.log(text)
      addToLogDiv('log', text)
    },
    info: function (text) {
      oldCons.info(text)
      addToLogDiv('info', text)
    },
    warn: function (text) {
      oldCons.warn(text)
      addToLogDiv('warn', text)
    },
    error: function (text) {
      oldCons.error(text)
      addToLogDiv('error', text)
    }
  }
})(window.console)

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console
```

I put the `<script src="../common/consoledebug.js"></script>` tag at the end of the HTML document, right before the `</body>` tag.

When I run inside a regular chrome window, I get these lines in my HTML body:

```
log: test

error: TypeError: $window.external.SomeProprietaryAPI is not a function
```

But Chrome's log shows an additional error `myhtml.html:35 Uncaught ReferenceError: someOtherProprietaryAPI is not defined at myhtml.html:35`

Any suggestions as to why this does not get captured by my function or what I can do about it? Or an alternative way to output *all* console output into the HTML document itself?

I tried including the script at the top of the file, but all that did was give me 2 errors on not being able to append to null (for the 2 log entries it's capturing, but not for the third one that it isn't).

I'm pretty new to Javascript and trying to get a base of existing AngularJS code working on a new version of the production environment that has switched from using IE to Chromium for HTML display.

Edit: Put enough code to be relevant in a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/wPAdE1rc397NHKOB?open=lib%2Fscript.js). As you can see the `console.log('test')` in the controller gets logged to the document, but the uncaught reference error in the body of the html document does not.

Edit six months later: Just wanted to note that the problem and its solution are still applicable in Angular12 using Typescript for the application (although the script that intercepts the console changes is a JS file loaded in the `"scripts":` array of my production configuration, not Typescript included in the project anywhere.)

Comment: When you say Angular you are talking about AngularJs (Angular 1.x)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.  Various files in the project also currently depend on *different* versions of AngularJS. It's painful.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a working demo in a sandbox site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some enhancements:

1. Create a message queue array for errors that occur before full dom has loaded.
2. Use `window.addEventListener('error', callback)` to listen for execution errors after new console defined
3. Wait for dom to load to query for the `logDiv`. Before it is defined push messages into the message queue and then when dom loads check for anything in that queue

```
let logDiv, messageQueue =[];

window.addEventListener('load', function(){
    // assign the log element
    logDiv = document.getElementById('logs');
    if(messageQueue.length){
        // print your preload errors
        messageQueue.forEach(([type,text])=>addToLogDiv(type,text))
    }
})

var addToLogDiv = function (type, text) {
  if(logDiv){
    var node = document.createElement('p')
    node.className = type
    var content = document.createTextNode(type + ': ' + text)
    node.appendChild(content)
    logDiv.appendChild(node)
  }else{
    // before logDiv defined store any errors
    messageQueue.push([type, text]) 
  } 
}

// define a new console
var console = (function (oldCons) {
  return {
    // same as before
  }
})(window.console)

//Then redefine the old console
window.console = console
// after new console created
window.addEventListener('error', function(e){
  console.log(e.message)
})
```

[Demo in head](https://plnkr.co/edit/cCxXn2vZBAiSff1u?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Thanks! Looks like that did the trick. I of course confused myself for a while trying to make it work in TypeScript, but it's working now and should help a lot in seeing what is and isn't working silently.