# Are there any security risks with using insertAdjacentHTML when wanting append HTML to a document?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, innerhtml, insertadjacenthtml

I have recently found out that using setInnerHtml is not good practice as there are plenty performance and security issues associated with it. So I am wondering whether replacing setInnerHtml with "insertAdjacentHTML" is fine?

Also, how should I go about completely refilling a table? As in removing the children of the parent element, the table body, and repopulating it with insertAdjacentHTML.

What I am currently doing

```
document.getElementById('myid').innerHTML = "";
const elm = document.getElementById("myid");
elm.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div></div>');
```

Does this practice defeat the purpose of using insertAdjacentHTML since I am still using innerHTML. When I set it empty with innerHTML, I am not doing any complex DOM manipulation, am I?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the HTML to be inserted is not trustworthy, `insertAdjacentHTML` could allow for arbitrary code execution.

```js
const evilInput = `<img src onerror="alert('evil')">`;
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', evilInput);
```

In terms of security, `insertAdjacentHTML` is not really better than `innerHTML` - what `insertAdjacentHTML` is useful for is when

- other elements in the container have a listener attached to them, and you don't want to corrupt the listeners by assigning to `innerHTML`. Or
- when you have a reference to an element and want to insert something next to it instead of taking a longer method (such as selecting the parent and then using [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore))

> Also, how should I go about completely refilling a table?

Setting the text content or `innerHTML` to the empty string and then choosing any of the *safe* approaches to insert elements anew is fine. (What qualifies as a safe approach depends on what exactly you're inserting. If it's from your trustworthy backend, for example, `innerHTML` and `insertAdjacentHTML` are both fine - use whatever makes the logic easiest)