# How to add an SVG as a child of a DIV?

Tags: javascript, html, svg, tags

In my HTML code, I have something like below:

```html
<div id="info">...</div>
<svg id="BarChart" class="chart" width="500" height="300" transform="translate(-110, 0) rotate(-90)">...</svg>
```

How can I make this SVG a child of the DIV using JavaScript?
I want to have a paragraph in div and then my chart.

Comment: Just use [`append`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/append)?

Comment: You need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5677799/how-to-append-text-to-a-div)

Comment: See also [How to move an element into another element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1279957/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using appendChild:

```
const BarChart = document.querySelector('#BarChart');
const info = document.querySelector('#info');
info.appendChild(BarChart);
```

Answer (score 1):

Find both `<div>` and `<svg>` by their IDs with [document.getElementById()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and use [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) API to add one to another.

```html
<div id="info">...</div>
<svg id="BarChart" class="chart" width="500" height="300" transform="translate(-110, 0) rotate(-90)">...</svg>

<script>
  const div = document.getElementById('info');
  const svg = document.getElementById('BarChart');
  div.appendChild(svg); // <- this will remove svg from it's previous location in DOM and append as the last element inside a div
</script>
```