# How can I use innerHTML without delete the before innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, html-table

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' onclick functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

I want to convert an Array to a HTML table, but innerHTML deletes it writes before. Here is the code:

```
<html><div id="tablaP"></div>

function cargar2() {
    document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML= "<table>"
    var h=1
    for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++){ 
        document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = '<tr>'
        for (j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++){              
            document.getElementById("tablaP").innerHTML = '<td><td>'
        }
        document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = '</tr>'
        h++
    }
    document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = '</table>'
}
```

Comment: Here's another SO question on the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this can easily be done by building up your html string and then applying it with one call:

```
function cargar2(){
    var h=1;//not sure why you have this
    var html = "";

    html += "<table>";

    for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++){ 
        html += '<tr>';

        for (j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++){              
            html += '<td></td>' ;                      
        }   

        html += '</tr>';
        h++;
    }

    html += '</table>';

    document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = html;
}
```

EDIT: Fixed all the code formatting!

Answer (score 0):

Use other approach. Build the whole table as a string, then do a single innerHTML.

That way it will be fast, and compatible with IE, that have a feew horrible related errors with adding rows to a table dynamically...

Answer (score 0):

Create a string variable and add the contents of the table into said variable, something like:

```
var h=1;
var table='<table>';
for(i=0;i<miArray.length;i++) {
    table+='<tr>';
    for(j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++) {
        table+='<td></td>';
    }
    table+='</tr>';
    h++;
}
document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML=table+'</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You should append all the table creation to a string and then finally assign the string to the innerHTML as shown below.

```
    function cargar2(){ 
       var tableCreation = "<table>"  
  var h=1 
  for (i=0;i<miArray.length;i++)
  {          
     tableCreation += '<tr>'     
     for (j=0;j<miArray[i].length;j++)
     {                      
        tableCreation += '<td></td>'             
      }       
     tableCreation += '</tr>' h++  
} 

document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = tableCreation;
```

Answer (score 0):

To do this efficiently, push the HTML fragments into an array, join the strings in the array into a single string, and use `innerHTML` to put it in the element:

```
function cargar2() {
  var html = ['<table>'];
  var h = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < miArray.length; i++) { 
    html.push('<tr>');
    for (j = 0; j < miArray[i].length; j++) {              
      html.push('<td><td>');
    }
    html.push('</tr>');
    h++;
  }
  html.push('</table>');
  document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = html.join('');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OMG How many things that sower the eye...

1. don't call document.GetElementByID() everytime you want the div!

   use a reference (variable) instead:

   var myTableDiv = document.getElementById('tablaP');

   myTableDiv.InnerHTML += ""

   myTableDiv.innerHTML += "";
2. I Mostly suggest setting up a string.. and only finally passing the InnerHTML.

   e.g.

   var myTableHTML = "";
   var h=1
   for (i=0;i';
       for (j=0;j
           myTableHTML += '';
       }
       myTableHTML += '';
       h++ 
   }
   document.getElementById('tablaP').innerHTML = myTableHTML;