# JavaScript function call inside inner.html

Tags: javascript, cordova, innerhtml

I have this html code with external function call and local variables:

```
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", "'+vivijesolo+'");"><img src="'+vivifoto+'" on;></a>';
```

The problem is that, it see's the variables and everthing is fine but the function cordova.exec can't be executable.

Why?? :(

Comment: The `"` is breaking the `onClick` attribute. it will only see `onClick="cordova.exec("` and then stop because the quote ends it

Comment: var func='cordova.exec("ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", "'+vivijesolo+'");';    
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML='<a href="#" onClick="cordova.exec("'+func+'"><img src="'+vivifoto+'" on;></a>'; try this, if it works, you need to change the way you use quotes.

Comment: violation of [soc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns#HTML.2C_CSS.2C_and_JavaScript)

Answer (score 2):

The `"` is breaking the `onClick` attribute. it will only see `onClick="cordova.exec("` and then stop because the quote ends it

Try this

```
var elem = document.getElementById("data");
elem.innerHTML = '<a href="#"><img src="'+vivifoto+'"></a>';

elem.firstChild.onclick = function() {
    cordova.exec( "ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage", vivijesolo );
};
```

Comment: one question, how can i push var elem.
    items.push('<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>');
i've tried but i always get an error [objectHTMLDivElement]

Comment: @BojanVidanovic can you make a new question with full code? I really need more context for that

Answer (score 0):

You must encode your event handler correctly:

```
onClick="cordova.exec(&quot;ChildBrowserCommand.showWebPage&quot;,&quot;'+vivijesolo+'&quot);"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a second problem here. I Dont think that you can create your event this way. Have a look at this question:

[Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

simply using innerHTML imho will not set up the event correctly.

Comment: The question you linked is a very different issue. Doing `.innerHTML +=` (The one and only thing I can say that one should **never** do with 110% confidence) always creates completely new elements as it serializes and unserializes from DOM to HTML and HTML to DOM so it cannot retain any context such as event handlers.