# Adding to innerHTML correct syntax

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

What is the correct syntax if I want to add content to an element using innerHTML.
Below is my non working example:

```
   openNewWindow: function(content) {
popupWin = window.open(content,
    'open_window',
    'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0')
},

for (var index in mv.exifImages) {
        ele.innerHTML += "<p onclick = openNewWindow(mv.exifImages[index]> image" + index + "</p>";
    }
```

Comment: I guess this should work `ele.innerHTML += "<p onclick ='openNewWindow(mv.exifImages[index])'> image" + index + "</p>";`

Comment: I get an Syntax error!

Answer (score 1):

i think it is. variable `index` has local scope

```
for (var index in mv.exifImages) {
        ele.innerHTML += "<p onclick = 'openNewWindow(\"" + mv.exifImages[index] + "\")'> image" + index + "</p>";
    }
```

Comment: whats mv.exifImages[index]? is it a string?

Comment: Try now. I have added an modification

Comment: SyntaxError: unterminated string literal @

Comment: did you split a string across lines

Answer (score 0):

Use `appendChild`:

```
var myelement = document.getElementById("myelement");
myelement.appendChild( document.createTextNode("Example text inside myelemen") );
```

This is better that overwriting innerHTML, as it preserves onclick events for example:
[Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

Answer (score 0):

innerHTML is not your problem, your code is lacking context.

```
    openNewWindow: function(content) {
        popupWin = window.open(content,
            'open_window',
            'menubar, toolbar, location, directories, status, scrollbars, resizable, dependent, width=640, height=480, left=0, top=0');
        // call to window.open ended here
    },
    // judging by the definition of openNewWindow and the comma above,
    // we are inside an object definition!

    // you cannot embed a for loop inside an object definition!!!
    for (var index in mv.exifImages) {
        ele.innerHTML += "<p onclick = openNewWindow(mv.exifImages[index]> image" + index + "</p>";
    }
```

Put your for loop somewhere sensible, like inside a function, or actually show us the error you are getting.

Comment: SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @

Comment: on which line? either show a complete code block or tell me where you intend to move your for loop to. the openWindow function is clearly part of an object, where's the rest? You need to close the object. Also, it would be wise to have a semi-colon after the call to window.open, as I have added in my answer.

Comment: you were not closing argument list with ')' in onclick

Comment: Pretty sure @Toms has got this, I'm voting up his answer.

Comment: The foor loop is inside another function. The object is to big to paste it here.

Comment: I just want a code that generates links which open contents of my exifImages array at proper index in a new window.