# How can I add rows to a table with this structure using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

How can I add rows to a table with this structure using Javascript?

Basically I want to be able to click a button and have a new row created within the table for each of the columns used below. So for instance, it could be name: new book, quantity:30 etc.

```
<table id="dynamictable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="name">My Favorite book</td>
            <td class="quantity">x&nbsp;20</td>
            <td class="unit_price">£8.99</td>
            <td class="total">£179.80</td>
            <td class="remove">
                <img src="image/cross.png">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/) See [ask advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask-advice), please.

Comment: have you heard about clone()? Learn about it.

Comment: I have always had good results with [JQuery-tmpl](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-tmpl), however it seems it is no longer maintained - works well still though

Comment: look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var newRow = '<tr><td class="name">New Book</td>[...]</tr>'; // add all your code here
$('#dynamictable tbody').append(newRow);
```

should do it (untested).

Answer (score 0):

Clone the first row on button click.  Fill in the new data.  Then append it to the table.

```
$( '#mybutton' ).click(function(){
    var tr = $('#dynamictable tr').eq(0).clone();

    tr.find('td').each(function(){
        $(this).html( 'Put Your Data Here.' );
    });

    $('#dynamictable').append(tr);


});
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4hrVQ/1/

Comment: That adds the same information under each heading. I want to be able to add
Name: Fantasy
Quantity:30
Unit_Price:2.30

Etc.

How do I do that with the above code

Comment: That depends on your data source.  What does the data source look like?