# copy innerHTML from one dropdownbox to another

Tags: javascript

I have 2 dropdownboxes.

```
<select id='SerK1'><option values="123">123</option></select>
<select id='SerK2'></select>
```

Then I wanna copy contents from SerK1 to SerK2

```
document.getElementById('SerK2').innerHTML+=document.getElementById('SerK1').innerHTML;
alert(document.getElementById('SerK1').innerHTML);
```

This prints out the expected result : 123

```
alert(document.getElementById('SerK2').innerHTML);
```

However, for this one, it somehow removes the  and came up with 
only 123 in the pop up alert screen.

Any ideas how to fix this?

Cheers

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do this with `jquery`
Try this

```
$('#SerK2').html($('#SerK1').html());
```

[Try This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSjWJ/1/)

Comment: well i was not going to do this with jquery. But anyway, thx.

Comment: if you don't want to use jquey then you can do it with document.getElementById('SerK2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('SerK1').innerHTML;

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
document.getElementById('SerK2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('SerK1').innerHTML;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSjWJ/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this --

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
     document.getElementById('SerK2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('SerK1').innerHTML
   });
```

[Try](http://jsfiddle.net/zSjWJ/2/)