# no output is displaying

Tags: javascript, html

The below code is my html code

### Star.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CssText.css">
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        Enter number of rows: <input type="text" name="t1" /> <input
            type="button" value="Display Diomond"
            onclick="return myFunction(this.form)" />
    </form>

<p id="p"></p>
<script src="StarPrint.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The below code is my javascript code

### StarPrint.js

```
function myFunction(form) {
    var no;
    no = form.t1.value;
    no = no / 2;
    var no2 = no;
    var no3 = no;
    var no4 = no;
    var no5 = no;
    var no6 = no;

    for ( var i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        for ( var index = 0; index < no2; index++) {
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML ="&nbsp&nbsp";
        }
        no2 = no2 - 1;

        for ( var index2 = 0; index2 < (i * 2) + 1; index2++) {
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "*";
        }
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML="</br>";
    }
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML="&nbsp&nbsp";
    for ( var i = 0; i < no3 + 1; i++) {

        for ( var index = 0; index <= i; index++) {
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "&nbsp&nbsp";
        }
        for ( var index2 = 0; index2 < (no4 * 2) - 3; index2++) {
            document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "*";
        }
        no4 = no4 - 1;
        document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "</br>&nbsp";
    }

}
```

I want to print pattern of diamond structure.The above program was working when I used document.write instead of document.getElementById("p").innerHTML with some modification.Where is that error I am not getting it.

Comment: You are doing `=` instead of `+=` on the `innerHTML` so it is probably getting overwritten. Also, there is no need for a `</br>`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu

Comment: Hi fiddle for u which works...http://jsbin.com/IcuSuzO/1/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not appending the stuff you want, but just assigning. Replace all `=` with `+=` like below:

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = "&nbsp&nbsp";
```

to

```
document.getElementById("p").innerHTML += "&nbsp&nbsp";
```

Comment: It's probably better if he just builds up that markup in a variable and assigns to `innerHTML` _once_ at the very end. Every `innerHTML` assignment causes parsing and DOM updates.

Answer (score 2):

You are replacing the content of `p` every time you call `document.getElementById("p").innerHTML =`.

Instead, save the text into a variable and only assign it to `p` at the end:

```
function myFunction(form) {
    var no;
    no = form.t1.value;
    no = no / 2;
    var no2 = no;
    var no3 = no;
    var no4 = no;
    var no5 = no;
    var no6 = no;
    var diamond = "";
    for ( var i = 0; i < no; i++) {
        for ( var index = 0; index < no2; index++) {
            diamond +="&nbsp&nbsp";
        }
        no2 = no2 - 1;

        for ( var index2 = 0; index2 < (i * 2) + 1; index2++) {
            diamond += "*";
        }
        diamond+="</br>";
    }
    diamond+="&nbsp&nbsp";
    for ( var i = 0; i < no3 + 1; i++) {

        for ( var index = 0; index <= i; index++) {
            diamond += "&nbsp&nbsp";
        }
        for ( var index2 = 0; index2 < (no4 * 2) - 3; index2++) {
            diamond += "*";
        }
        no4 = no4 - 1;
        diamond  += "</br>&nbsp";
    }
    document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = diamond;
}
```

Working Example - http://jsfiddle.net/fdadE/