# Why do I lose reference to an element?

Tags: javascript

I stumbled upon something peculiar (at least to me). Here is the case:

I select an element, *child1*, from the DOM and save it to a variable. I continue on by adding a new element to *child1*'s parent, *parent1*. Now if I try to modify some value on *child1* it does not register the change. It seems as though the reference has disappeared and it is only referring to an earlier copy.

**EXAMPLE**
*child1* = inputField
*parent1* = container

```
function start() {
    var inputField = document.querySelector('#inputField');
    // Works if addSomething() is commented out.
    addSomething();
    console.log(inputField);
    doSomething(inputField);
}

function addSomething() {
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    container.innerHTML += '<div class="something"></div>'
}

function doSomething(el) {
    el.value = 'Some random input';
}

start();
```

**EXAMPLE FIDDLE**

http://jsfiddle.net/mdTkZ/

Excuse me if this is something incredibly basic or something that has been asked before. I tried googling, but did not find anything with the search words I used. A

Comment: try `console.log(inputField.value)` after `doSomething`. It is getting modified. What do you want exactly ?

Comment: I don't want to achieve anything in particular, actually. I just want to get a better understanding of how stuff works :p.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`container.innerHTML += ...` doesn't do what you think it does. It re-creates all the HTML to the element, and the original content is gone.

To fix this you need to create a new `div` and append it to `container`.

```
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.className = 'something';
container.appendChild(div);
```

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQuRZ/1/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Teemu! Considering the the original content is gone when doing the 'container.innerHTML += ...' why does the inputField variable seem to contain the correct element? How come it is not turned into undefined or null? Is a copy generated and it references the copy?

Comment: No, it's not a copy. You've still a reference (`inputField` and later `el` variables) to the original `input`. The element is removed from the DOM, but it remains available to the script (the removed element is in a same kind of a state as the `div` in my fix code just before `appendChild()`, i.e. it is created, but it has not parent element, hence you can't see it.) untill `inputField` and `el` are deleted. You can even [append the original element back](http://jsfiddle.net/pj8W9/) to the document, as long as a reference to it is alive.

Comment: For this reason, I consider `element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class="something"></div>")` to be a much better way of appending HTML to an element.

Comment: @Tikolu Which method to use depends on the actual use-case. It's easy to avoid memory leaks when using block scoped variables (or a function in this old ES3 code).

Answer (score 1):

You are replacing the entire DOM subtree by setting innertHTML. `inputField` is now detached from its parent. You can check it by logging `inputField.parentNode === null`.

You can use `insertAdjacentHTML` instead.

```
function addSomething() {
    var container = document.querySelector('#container');
    container.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<div class="something"></div>');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tarabyte/mdTkZ/1/

Answer (score 1):

When replacing innerHTML on object you removing inputField from the DOM so the object changes does not register in the browser

```
container.innerHTML += '<div class="something"></div>'
```

You actually do

```
container.innerHTML = container.innerHTML + '<div class="something"></div>';
```

Comment: For this reason, I consider `element.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "<div class="something"></div>")` to be a much better way of appending HTML to an element.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `container.innerHTML += '<div class="something"></div>'`, it replaces the content with some other `text`.

`inputField` which you had before changing `innerHTML`, was holding a reference to DOM object. But now, that is destroyed and is replaced by just a string. You would need to access/select that `input` from DOM again ( by `document.querySelector('#inputField');` ) to use it.

Answer (score 0):

From this: [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

"Unfortunately, assignment to innerHTML causes the destruction of all child elements, even if you're trying to append"

You could use: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.insertAdjacentHTML

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this
    var inputField;
    function start() 
    {
        inputField = document.getElementById('inputField');
        // Works if addSomething() is commented out.
        addSomething();
        console.log(inputField);
        doSomething(inputField);
    }

    function addSomething() 
    {
        var t=document.getElementById('container').innerHTML;
        document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = t+'<div class="something"></div>'
    }

    function doSomething(el) 
    {
        el.value = 'Some random input';
    }

    start()
```