# Function does not recognize initialized variable

Tags: javascript, function, variables

Apologies, I don't have formal training in Javascript. I am trying to make a function that operates a loading progress bar. I'd like to add the "donezo" class to #ammount upon completion. However, the class is not being added. I believe the variables are initialized correctly. Doing a querySelector instead of the "ammount" var does seem to work. Hopefully someone can explain why this is the case to me? Much appreciated.

[codepen here](http://codepen.io/kamtr0n/pen/eZoeBG/)

```
(function move() {
    var ammount = document.getElementById("ammount");
    var counter = document.getElementById("counter");
    var wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper");
    var status = 1;
    var loader = setInterval(fireZeLoader, 10);

    function fireZeLoader() {
        if (status >= 100) {
            clearInterval(loader);
            wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + '<div class="finished">Complete</div>';
            ammount.classList.add("donezo");
        } else {
            status++;
            ammount.style.width = status + '%';
            counter.innerHTML = status + '%';
        }
    }
}());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because when you modify `wrapper.innerHTML` the DOM inside `wrapper` is re-created. That is, all references that you've got beforehand are now pointing to objects which are not on the screen anymore. You can swap these two lines:

```
ammount.classList.add("donezo");
wrapper.innerHTML = wrapper.innerHTML + '<div class="finished">Complete</div>';
```

Another option is to [carefully modify DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu) without assigning to `innerHTML`, I'd recommend doing the latter.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized I've been spelling "amount" incorrectly too, haha.

Comment: @user5494847 glad it helped. If you think my answer fully answers your question, please accept it ([more info](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))