# Multiple C3.js charts automatically hidden, except the last one

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

I am trying to generate multiple c3 charts with the following code :

```
var datas=[[
    ["name", "position", "y", "bigRect", "myBars"],
    ["One 22", 2, 2, 2, 2],
    ["One 33", 3, 3, 2, 2],
    ["One 44", 4, 4, 2, 2]
],[
    ["name", "position", "y", "bigRect", "myBars"],
    ["Two 55", 5, 5, 2, 2],
    ["Two 66", 6, 6, 2, 2],
    ["Two 77", 7, 7, 2, 2]
],[
    ["name", "position", "y", "bigRect", "myBars"],
    ["Three 88", 8, 8, 2, 2],
    ["Three 99", 9, 9, 2, 2],
    ["Three 00", 0, 0, 2, 2]
]];

var iData = 0;
var charts = [];

for(iData in datas){

    var d = datas[iData];
    document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML += "<div id='chart"+iData+"'></div>";
    var chartSelector = "#chart"+iData;

    charts[iData] = c3.generate({
        bindto: d3.select(chartSelector),
        data: {
            rows: d,
            type: "scatter",
            types: {
                bigRect: "area",
                myBars: "bar"
            },
            x: "position",
            y: "y"
        },
        zoom: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });

}
```

All the charts look empty except the last one that works perfectly. **You can see what it looks like on [this JSbin link](http://jsbin.com/guxamofuso/edit?html,output%20%22JS%20Bin).**

On the hidden charts, all the SVGs are generated, but

- the `g` SVG elements that contain the `path` drawing the dots and bars are set on `opacity: 0`, hiding all their contents.
- the zoom and the tooltip do not work either

Do you know why c3 is disabling the first charts and how to enable them ?

My apologies for my poor English and thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got it working now, but I can also get it working by replacing one line like so:

```
   d3.select(".container").append("div").attr("id", "chart"+iData);
    //document.querySelector(".container").innerHTML += "<div id='chart"+iData+"'></div>";
```

It appears adding stuff to and then replacing .innerHtml has side effects for the existing contents, in your case the first charts you build

[Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-onclick-fu)

This includes wiping out event handlers and 'unofficial' (for want of a better term) attributes like the `__data__` field d3 populates and uses (it's undefined for the first 2 sets of bars as this code will reveal)

```
  for(iData in datas){
    console.log (d3.select("#chart"+iData+" .c3-bars").node().__data__);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved my problem by creating all the `#chartX` containers in another loop before that calling `c3`.

I assume it has something to do with the non-procedural execution order of JS but I'm still looking for a precise explanation of the phenomenon.
Here is the [link to the corrected JSbin](http://jsbin.com/repenobaqo/1/edit?html,output).