# JavaScript button.onclick doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, onload, getelementbyid

I recently started learning how to use JavaScript in my webpage. My exercise today is to make a *button* that can give me a *V shape*.

The **code** to create the *V shape* is fine, but it doesn't work when I try to put it in a click handler (i.e. `oBtn.click = function (){};`).

In the HTML document I have the following code:

```
<style>
    div{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px red solid;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function (){
        var oBody = document.getElementById('body');
        var aDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var oBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            oBody.innerHTML += '<div>'+ i +'</div>';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.left =i*50+'px';
        }

        oBtn1.onclick = function (){
        for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length/2; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.top = 40+i*50+'px';
        }
        var x = aDiv.length;
        for (var i = 4; i < x; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.top =x*50-i*50-50+40+'px';    
        }
        };
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Try using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of setting the onclick handler directly.  `oBtn1.addEventListener("click", function() { ... } );`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)

Answer (score -1):

I believe this is close to what you wanted.  Runs in chrome, but may not in other browsers (notably IE).  Doesn't work as a snippet, sorry.  I suspect trying to modify all divs in the body is going to cause you trouble in the long term.  A couple of things to notice:

- You don't need to get the body by name, you can just use `document.body` (I'm making an assumption here - however giving an element the id "body" could easily cause confusion)
- Your divs must be created before you try to get the array from the DOM
- Event handlers are done using the commonly preferred method.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
    div{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px red solid;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
    }
</style><script>
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        document.body.innerHTML += '<div>'+ i +'</div>';
    }

    var aDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length; i++) {
        aDiv[i].style.left =i*50+'px';
    }

    document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", function () {
        for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length/2; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.top = 40+i*50+'px';
        }
        var x = aDiv.length;
        for (var i = 4; i < x; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.top =x*50-i*50-50+40+'px';
        }
    });
}, false);
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="button" id="btn1"><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

If I understand this right, you want to execute 'oBtn1.onclick' as a click event? If so, do something like this

```
function buttonClick (){
for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length/2; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.top = 40+i*50+'px';
}

oBtn1.addEventListener('click', buttonClick);
```

what that will do is as soon as the element that contains the id 'oBtn1' is clicked it will execute your for loop.

Answer (score -2):

What does your html look like? If it looks kind of like the below snippet then it should be working, though you should look at using [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) for this kind of thing.

```js
    window.onload = function (){
        var oBody = document.getElementById('body');
        var aDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
        var oBtn1 = document.getElementById('btn1');

        for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            oBody.innerHTML += '<div>'+ i +'</div>';
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length; i++) {
            aDiv[i].style.left =i*50+'px';
        }

        oBtn1.onclick = function (){
            for (var i = 0; i < aDiv.length/2; i++) {
                aDiv[i].style.top = 40+i*50+'px';
            }
            var x = aDiv.length;
            for (var i = 4; i < x; i++) {
                aDiv[i].style.top =x*50-i*50-50+40+'px';    
            }
        };
    };
```

```css
div{
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        border: 1px red solid;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 50px;
        text-align: center;
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

```html
<button id="btn1">press</button>
<div id="body"></div>
```