# Input button stop working when filling the div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a div in my html defined like this:

```
<div id="rgroups" class="dialogWindow fileDialog"  style="display:none;" >
<input id="rgroups_ok" class="dialogButton" type="submit" value="Done"/> 
<label for="rgroups_ok"><span class="label">Start</span></label>';
</div>
```

In my js file the rgroups_ok is define that way:

```
$('rgroups_ok').observe('click', function ()
{
ui.hideDialog('rgroups');
});
```

If I keep to that it's working fine, the button is working.

Then I am filling that html div like that:

```
var div=document.getElementById('rgroups');
div.style.display='inline-block';
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
div.innerHTML+=' Rgroup '+i+' values separated by / symbol:  \n <textarea id="Rgroup"'+i+' rows="4" cols="50"> </textarea>';}
```

With that inner HTML defines button stops working...

Any clue?

Thanks

Comment: Using append() instead of string concatenation with innerHTML property migth help. Also using JQuery's on() event is better to use than observe() and bind(), generally.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing **observe** to **on**
so this:

```
    $('#rgroups_ok').on('click', function ()
    {
        ui.hideDialog('rgroups');
    });
```

You can check the details for [on() here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Observe seems to be [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) and may not be a thing you are looking for.

Comment: not changinr anything. I precise the observe is working while I am not writing html from my js.

Comment: observe is not working fine, first of all you misuse it 2nd parameter should be the object to observe, instead you try to pass there a string ? I have added # to the jquery selector, this should make it work with on('click')

Answer (score 0):

I could not understand clearly. so I made demo code.

If you could mention your main subject/idea it would help us.

Full code:
Head:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Body:

```
<div id="rgroups" class="dialogWindow fileDialog">
        <label for="rgroups_ok">
            <span class="label">Start</span>
        </label>
    </div>

<div id="rgroups2" style="display:none;">
    <p onclick="textA()">Hey click here</p>
</div>

<button id="rgroups_ok2" class="dialogButton" onclick="a()">
    Done
</button>
<script>
    function a() {
        $('#rgroups').css("display", "none");
        $("#rgroups2").css("display", "inline-block");
        $("#rgroups_ok2").css("display", "none");
    };


    function textA() {
        var count = 100;
        //document.getElementById("rgroups2").innerHTML += "Bye";
        for (i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
            document.getElementById("rgroups2").innerHTML += '<p> Rgroup ' + i + ' values separated by / symbol:  \n <textarea id="Rgroup" rows="4" cols="50">' + i + ' </textarea></p>';
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi found the solution on this post:
[Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)

To sum up it's not possible to append without destroying all child. Ths the event have to be reconstructed.

Thanks