# JavaScript doesn't work after appending new element

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem when appending new element with JavaScript. I don't use any library such as jQuery or anything else, i'm using native JavaScript while doing this.

Okay, i'm trying to append a new element to the `<body>` tag. If in jQuery you can use the `.append()` function, but when using native JavaScript you must use `.innerHTML`.

Here's my HTML code

```
<button id="add">
Add
</button>
```

Here's my JavaScript code

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].innerHTML += '<p>Hello world</p>';
});
```

When i click the 'add' button it's works the first time. But, when i click again it doesn't work. When i try to use jQuery to append new element then it works, is there any less?

Comment: *but when using native JavaScript you must use `innerHTML`* Where did you learn that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)

Comment: fun fact: jquery is not using innerHTML for this

Comment: @torazaburo I learned it myself, so what should I use?

Comment: I think I have the wrong thinking about appending in JavaScript :D

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're replacing the entire contents of your body with all new contents, wiping out any elements and any events attached to them.

Don't overwrite `.innerHTML`. Use `.appendChild()`:

```js
document.getElementById('add').addEventListener('click', function() {
    var p = document.createElement('p');
    p.textContent = 'Hello world';

    document.body.appendChild(p);
});
```

```html
<button id="add">Add</button>
```

Comment: Whoa, now i know the right way to append a new element, thanks sir!

Answer (score 1):

Or, if you're going to be appending more than one item, create a document fragment, do all your preliminary work on that, then append that to the DOM. The advantage of this method is that the DOM will only be redrawn once. Example:

```
var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();

var topSquare = document.createElement('div');
frag.appendChild(topSquare);

var rightSquare = document.createElement('div');
frag.appendChild(rightSquare);

document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(frag);
```

Or, if you absolutely have to use an HTML string for some reason, use this method:

```
var htmlString = '<p>Hello world</p>';
var para = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(htmlString);
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(para);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
   
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
 
 document.getElementById("k").innerHTML += '<p>Hello world</p>';

});
```

```html
<button id="add">
Add
</button>
<div id= "k"></div>
```