# addEventListener on programatically created checkbox not working

Tags: javascript, events, checkbox, addeventlistener

I've made a function that takes a `select multiple` input and generate checkboxes based on the options of this select. Then, I want that each checkbox execute some action when clicked. The function is:

```
const makeCheckboxDropdown = (input) => {
    if (input.type !== "select-multiple") {
        console.error("The input must be an `select multiple` type!")
        return
    }

    input.options[0].selected = false

    const header = document.getElementById('header')
    const outer = document.createElement('div')
    const options = input.options
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        let div = document.createElement('div')
        div.classList.add('checkbox')

        let label = document.createElement('label')

        let cb = document.createElement('input')
        cb.type = "checkbox"
        cb.value = options[i].value
        cb.addEventListener("change", (e) => console.log("clicked"))

        label.appendChild(cb)
        label.innerHTML += options[i].value

        div.appendChild(label)
        outer.appendChild(div)
    }
    header.parentNode.insertBefore(outer, header.nextSibiling)
}
```

Everything works: the checkbox are generated as intended. Except that, when I click the checkboxes, nothing happens. It should log "clicked" on console, but nothing happens. Strangely, if I add this same EventListener through browser debug console, it works.

What is happening here?

**Edit:** an [repl.it](https://repl.it/@mateusfccp/DisguisedReflectingCutworm) example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with you using `innerHTML` on the label after you have already appended the checkbox. One alternative that works is a slight modification as below. What I've done is append another element (a span, you might also use `document.createTextNode`) with the value. This action is safe since I am not using `innerHTML` on the element that has the checkbox inside of it.

An explanation of what `innerHTML` is doing can be seen in this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list).

I believe you could also fix this by getting the checkbox again after you have modified the HTML with `innerHTML` (for example using `children` on your `label` DOM element) and applying the listener at that point, but I wouldn't recommend that method.

```js
function ready(fn) {
  if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading"){
    fn();
  } else {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
  }
}

function theFunc(e) {
  console.log('clicked');
}

ready(() => {
  const makeCheckboxDropdown = (input) => {
    if (input.type !== "select-multiple") {
        console.error("The input must be an `select multiple` type!");
        return;
    }

    input.options[0].selected = false;
    
    const header = document.getElementById('header');
    const outer = document.createElement('div');
    const options = input.options;
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      let div = document.createElement('div');
      div.classList.add('checkbox');

      let label = document.createElement('label');

      let cb = document.createElement('input');
      cb.type = "checkbox";
      cb.value = options[i].value;
      cb.addEventListener('change', theFunc);

      label.appendChild(cb);
      
      let value = document.createElement('span');
      value.textContent = options[i].value;
      label.appendChild(value);

      div.appendChild(label);
      outer.appendChild(div);
    }
    header.parentNode.insertBefore(outer, header.nextSibiling);
  };

  const a = document.getElementById('a');
  makeCheckboxDropdown(a);
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>repl.it</title>
    <link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
    <div class="content">
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="box box-primary">
            <div class="box-body">
                <h4 id="header">Dias da Semana</h4>
                <select id="a" multiple>
                    <option>1:00 am</option>
                    <option>2:00 am</option>
                    <option>3:00 am</option>
                    <option>4:00 am</option>
                    <option>5:00 am</option>
                    <option>6:00 am</option>
                    <option>7:00 am</option>
                    <option>8:00 am</option>
                    <option>9:00 am</option>
                    <option>10:00 am</option>
                    <option>11:00 am</option>
                    <option>12:00 pm</option>
                    <option>13:00 pm</option>
                    <option>14:00 pm</option>
                    <option>15:00 pm</option>
                    <option>16:00 pm</option>
                    <option>17:00 pm</option>
                    <option>18:00 pm</option>
                    <option>19:00 pm</option>
                    <option>20:00 pm</option>
                    <option>21:00 pm</option>
                    <option>22:00 pm</option>
                    <option>23:00 pm</option>
                    <option>00:00 am</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I solved it by changing `label.innerHTML += [...]` for `label.appendChild(document.createTextNode([...]))` as the link in your answer suggests.