# Creation of buttons and eventlisteners using javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function that will add buttons with their corresponding event listeners

```
var wordCount = 0;
function createButton(word, alert){
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += "<button id=\"word-" + wordCount + "\">" + word + "</button>";
    document.querySelector('#word-' + wordCount).addEventListener('click', function(){
        console.log(alert);
    })
    wordCount++;
}

createButton('a', 'A');
createButton('b', 'B');
```

Only the last **button(b)** responds. Clicking **button(a)** does not output anything. 
How would you fix this? Are there better ways that I could have implemented this?

Comment: Instead of `innerHTML` we can go with `createElement()`

Comment: Please check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list

Answer (score 0):

I am frequently facing this situation and doing it in a simpler way. see this, (the beauty of the method is if you start the variable full with single quotes, you can add any usual double quoted stuff within it, with ease and without any escaping issues). No addEventListener business needed here. :-)

```js
var full = '';
var wordCount = 0;

function createButton(word, alert) {
    alert='\''  + alert + '\'';
  full = full + '<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="alert(' + alert + ');">'

  full = full + '<button id="word-' + wordCount + '" >' + word + '</button>';

  full = full + '</a>';

  document.querySelector('body').innerHTML += full;
  wordCount++;
}

function anyFunction(alert) {
  console.log(alert);
}

createButton('a', 'A');
createButton('b', 'B');
```

Comment: If you can create the stack snippet, that will be more understandable for the OP

Comment: I am also New to Stackoverflow.  Don't know how to add stack snippet. I will post full working code instead.

Comment: I've edited and added the snippet to your question, approve it

Comment: Thank you.  I have further edited it. It is working now.