# Using template strings to append HTML

Tags: javascript, dom

New to es6, is there a way to append HTML using template literals `` in the DOM without overwriting what was currently posted?

I have a huge block of HTML that I need to post for a list that is being created. Where a user is able to post their input.

Every-time the task is submitted it overwrites the current submission. I need it to append underneath.

fiddle for demonstration purpose.

https://jsfiddle.net/uw1o5hyr/5/

```
 <div class = main-content> 

 <form class ='new-items-create'>

 <label>Name:</label><input placeholder=" A Name" id="name">


 <button class = "subBtn">Submit</button>

 </form>


 </div>

  <span class="new-name"></span>


JavaScript

form.addEventListener('submit',addItem);

 function addItem(event){
 event.preventDefault();
 let htmlStuff = 
    ` 
     <div class="main">
    <div class="a name">
     <span>${name.value}</span>
    </div>
    <div>
    `

   itemCreated.innerHTML = htmlStuff;


   }
```

Comment: `itemCreated.innerHTML += htmlStuff`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[`insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) adds htmlString in 4 positions see demo. Unlike `.innerHTML` it never rerenders and destroys the original HTML and references. The only thing `.innerHTML` does that `insertAdjacentHTML()` can't is to read HTML. **Note: assignment by `.innerHTML` always destroys everything even when using `+=` operator. See this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/595825/2813224)**

```js
const sec = document.querySelector('section');

sec.insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', `<div class='front-element'>Front of Element</div>`)

sec.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', `<div class='before-content'>Before Content</div>`)

sec.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<div class='after-content'>After Content</div>`)

sec.insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', `<div class='behind-element'>Behind Element</div>`)
```

```css
* {
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

section {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-style: dashed;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
}

.front-element {
  outline-color: gold;
}

.before-content {
  outline-color: blue;
}

.after-content {
  outline-color: green;
}

.behind-element {
  outline-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section>CONTENT OF SECTION</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just use `+=` to append:

```js
document.getElementById('div').innerHTML += 'World';
```

```html
<div id="div">
  Hello
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Element.prototype.appendTemplate = function (html) {
    this.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', html);
    return this.lastChild;
};
```

If you create the element prototype as per above, you can get the element back as reference so you can continue modifying it:

```
   for (var sectionData of data) {
        var section = target.appendTemplate(`<div><h2>${sectionData.hdr}</h2></div>`);

        for (var query of sectionData.qs) {
            section.appendTemplate(`<div>${query.q}</div>`);
        }
    }
```

Depending on how much you're doing, maybe you'd be better off with a templating engine, but this could get you pretty far without the weight.