# Not able to mark checkboxes checked dynamically through javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making a todo app using javascript. I am dynamically creating a template for tasks that i will be entering in a input box. On clicking add task template is created dynamically and that template contains the name of task and one checkbox. I tried changing the checked property to true. In console also its showing true but in web browser checkbox is not checked

Here is my code for dynamically adding task

```
function updateLists(tasks){
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    tasks.forEach((task,index)=>{
        const divP = document.createElement('div');
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerText = task.task;
        div.style.textDecoration = task.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none';
        divP.className = 'taskdiv';
        divP.id = index;
        const span = document.createElement('img');
        span.src = 'trash.svg';
        span.className = 'taskSpan'
        const span2 = document.createElement('span');
        const inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        inputEl.type = 'checkbox';
        inputEl.className = 'checkbox';
        console.log(task.completed);
        inputEl.checked = true;
        span2.appendChild(inputEl);
        span2.className = 'checkSpan'
        divP.appendChild(span2);
        span.className = 'taskSpan'
        divP.append(div);
        divP.append(span);
        parent.prepend(divP);
    })
    parentDiv.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried appending the checkbox and only after marking it as checked?

Answer (score 4):

You seem to be looking for the [defaultChecked](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_checkbox_defaultchecked.asp) property:

```js
var parentDiv = document.getElementById('tasks');

updateLists([{task: 'pending', completed: false}, {task: 'completed', completed: true}]);

function updateLists(tasks){
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
    tasks.forEach((task,index)=>{
        const divP = document.createElement('div');
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerText = task.task;
        div.style.textDecoration = task.completed ? 'line-through' : 'none';
        divP.className = 'taskdiv';
        divP.id = index;
        const span = document.createElement('img');
        span.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/15';
        span.className = 'taskSpan'
        const span2 = document.createElement('span');
        const inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        inputEl.type = 'checkbox';
        inputEl.className = 'checkbox';
        console.log(task.completed);
        inputEl.checked = task.completed;
        inputEl.defaultChecked = task.completed;
        span2.appendChild(inputEl);
        span2.className = 'checkSpan'
        divP.appendChild(span2);
        span.className = 'taskSpan'
        divP.append(div);
        divP.append(span);
        parent.prepend(divP);
    })
    parentDiv.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="tasks">tasks</div>
```

Or use DOM functions like [appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to preserve the child nodes instead of innerHTML.

Comment: i found the strange behaviour if i am writing parentDiv.appendChild(parent) then checkboxes are perfectly working but if i write parentDiv.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML not working

Comment: By assigning the `defaultChecked` it works in both cases, check it

Comment: ya its working bro but another strange thing happening because of using innerhtml that if i try to add any eventlistener lets say i add eventlistener to my span2 in above code its not working but with appendChild its working. Do you know the reason

Comment: That's because appendChild is a DOM function and preserves the child nodes. There are some answers of this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list

Comment: I'm glad I could help

Comment: Can you answer one more thing how can I make listener work with inner html or is there any DOM function that can append the div inside parent by  overwriting the parent div

Comment: With DOM functions you can delete all the children of an element: `while (element.firstChild) { element.removeChild(element.firstChild); }` and then use `element.appendChild()` for example

Comment: Thanku I will try it

Answer (score 0):

once you append, grab the element and set the checkbox;

```js
function updateLists(){
    const parent = document.createElement('div');
   
        const divP = document.createElement('div');
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        div.innerText = "hi there";
        div.style.textDecoration = 'line-through' ;
        divP.className = 'taskdiv';
        divP.id = "aa";
        
        const span = document.createElement('img');
        span.src = 'trash.svg';
        span.className = 'taskSpan'
        const span2 = document.createElement('span');
        const inputEl = document.createElement('input');
        inputEl.type = 'checkbox';
        inputEl.className = 'checkbox';
       
        inputEl.id = "bb";
        span2.appendChild(inputEl);
        span2.className = 'checkSpan';
        divP.appendChild(span2);
        span.className = 'taskSpan';
        divP.append(div);
        divP.append(span);
        parent.prepend(divP);
        
        var parentDiv=document.getElementById("xx");
        console.log(parentDiv);
    
    parentDiv.innerHTML = parent.innerHTML;
    console.log(inputEl );
    document.getElementById('bb').checked=true;
}

updateLists()
```

```html
<div id="xx">x</div>
```