# how can I set a setInterval as a global variable?

Tags: javascript, html

I just wanna make a button to start adding some text in my body, and a button to stop adding this text.

I figured out that I can use a setTimeout in a function or a setInterval...but I couldn't Clear both of them because of the local scope...I can't declare both of them as a global scope, I want my button.onclick activate them not by default.

```js
/* global document*/
 
      
var myStart = document.querySelector('#start'),
        myEnd = document.querySelector('#end'),
        myRepeat;

function start() {
    "use strict";
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>Welcome StackOverFlowMembers!';
    myRepeat = setTimeout(start, 1000)
}

function stop() {
    "use strict";
    clearTimeout(myRepeat);
}

myStart.onclick = start;
myEnd.onclick = stop;
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="start">Start!</button>
    <button id="end">End!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not the scope of the variables. Everything is actually fine with your code on that.

The problem is here:

```
document.body.innerHTML += '<br>Welcome StackOverFlowMembers!';
```

If you replace it with:

```
console.log('Hello!');
```

Both buttons will work normally. Check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/anpel13/v5yud81e/5/).

Basically, when you use `innerHTML` you destroy the event listeners. You can find more on that in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)

Answer (score 0):

As @anpel's answer explains, your `innerHTML` call is trashing your event listeners. In the code below, I work around that by putting the `onclick` attribute directly into the HTML button elements.  The boolean `doRepeat` variable governs whether a subsequent timeout gets initiated.

```js
/* global document*/      
var myStart = document.querySelector('#start'),
        myEnd = document.querySelector('#end'),
        doRepeat;

function start() {
    "use strict";
    document.body.innerHTML += '<br>Welcome StackOverFlowMembers!';
    if (doRepeat) {
       setTimeout(start, 1000);
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <button id="start" onclick="doRepeat=true;start();">Start!</button>
    <button id="end" onclick="doRepeat=false;">End!</button>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
```

Alternatively, you can make a separate `<div>` into which your function writes its text-- instead how you're doing `innerHTML` to the ***entire HTML body***, which destroys all child listeners-- and you won't have to worry about your event listeners getting destroyed since those listeners aren't on children of the target div.

Here's a JS Fiddle to demonstrate that: https://jsfiddle.net/j9voxg7s/