# How to print data without overriding?

Tags: javascript

I have an script that prints each letter of an string and how many times it is printed, but it is not working properly, it overrides the last letter.
For example: when you type in the textarea "assist" it should print the following:
a: 1
s: 3
i: 1
t: 1
But it only prints:
t: 1
How to print properly the string?

```js
function ex44() {
  let string = document.getElementById("sarc4").value
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  const count = {}
  string.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1
      return
    }
    count[ch]++
  })
  for (const key in count) {
    document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = `${key} : ${count[key]}`
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

Comment: unsurprising, since you are *overwriting* the `.innerHTML` of `#result4` for each `key` in `count`.

Comment: It's in your `for(const key incount)` loop.

Comment: you need to accumulate those entries into a string using `+=`, and then just write that _once_ into `#result4` _outside the loop_.

Comment: Thanks guys, sorry for disturbing, I am new to Javascript

Comment: @Andy no, no, no.   Never use `+=` on `.innerHTML`.   It requires the browser to convert the HTML back into a string, and then you modify the string, and then the browser has to convert it back into DOM, _for every iteration_.

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = `${key} : ${count[key]}`
```

Will **override** the `innerHTML`.

Consider 'adding' the content using `appendChild` or `insertAdjacentHTML`:
<sup>[Is it possible to append to innerHTML without destroying descendants' event listeners?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list)</sup>

```js
const res = document.getElementById("result4");
for (const key in count) {
    res.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${key} : ${count[key]}</p>`);
}
```

```js
function ex44() {
  let string = document.getElementById("sarc4").value
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  const count = {}
  string.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1
      return
    }
    count[ch]++
  })
  const res = document.getElementById("result4");
  for (const key in count) {
    res.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${key} : ${count[key]}</p>`);
  }
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

**Note**: I've wrapped the `${key} : ${count[key]}` inside a `<p></p>` tag so we see each letter on a separate row

---

Another option is to create an `output` string by using `map` and `join` like so:

```js
const output = Object.keys(count).map((key) => `<p>${key} : ${count[key]}</p>`);
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = output.join('');
```

```js
function ex44() {
  const input = document.getElementById("sarc4").value.toLowerCase();
  const count = {}
  
  input.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1;
    } else {
      count[ch]++
    }
  });
   
  const output = Object.keys(count).map((key) => `<p>${key} : ${count[key]}</p>`);
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = output.join('');
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5">test</textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

Comment: No, no, no.   Never use `+=` on `.innerHTML`.   It requires the browser to convert the HTML back into a string, and then you modify the string, and then the browser has to convert it back into DOM, destroying and recreating the DOM elements, _for every iteration_.

Comment: You're right @Alnitak, trying to be too fast. I've improved my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML` outside the loop.

You are rewritting the `innerHTML` of the element with id `result4` each time the loop is executing. You can update the innerHTML by appending the new striing with existing by using below to get the issue fixed.

```
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML += `${key} : ${count[key]}`
```

The above implementation cannot be considered as a good implementation even though it's fixes your problem. Accessing DOM elements directly from script is always costly. If it's inside a loop a loop it's definitely more costly.

Instead of accessing the DOM element multiple time from a loop, you could create the template string inside the loop and assign the `innerHTML` only once as below. This will be better in terms of performance.

```js
function ex44() {
  let string = document.getElementById("sarc4").value
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  let template = '';
  const count = {}
  string.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1
      return
    }
    count[ch]++
  })
  for (const key in count) {
    template += `${key} : ${count[key]}`
  }
  document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = template;
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

Comment: see other comments about why you shouldn't use `+=` with `.innerHTML`.   Please, just remove that from your answer entirely.

Comment: I too don't suggest to use += with innerHTML. Please see updated answer.

Comment: _someone_ will read your first line of code, and think it's a good idea, without reading the following text about the consequences.   It isn't even just about performance.  Using `+=` destroys the original child elements, _including any event handlers registered on them_.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Object.keys(count)` to foreach. And currently, you are overwriting the result's HTML on loop. So I use a `newHtml` variable to save it and set it into `innerHTML` outside loop.

```js
function ex44() {
  let string = document.getElementById("sarc4").value
  string = string.toLowerCase();
  const count = {}
  string.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1
      return
    }
    count[ch]++
  })
  
  var newHtml = '';
  for (const key of Object.keys(count)) {
    newHtml += `${key} : ${count[key]} <br/>`
  }
document.getElementById("result4").innerHTML = newHtml;
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

Comment: there's absolutely nothing wrong with `for (const key in count)`.   No sane person adds enumerable properties to `Object.prototype` any more.

Comment: alternatively use `for (const [ch, n] of Object.entries(count))` and get the key _and_ value together.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks for your suggestion. It's a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Cache your elements, and then use `textContent` to update the element text using string concatenation.

```js
const sarc4 = document.getElementById('sarc4');
const result4 = document.getElementById('result4');

function ex44() {
  string = sarc4.value.toLowerCase();
  const count = {};
  string.split("").forEach(ch => {
    if (!count[ch]) {
      count[ch] = 1;
      return;
    }
    count[ch]++
  });
  let result = '';
  for (const key in count) {
    result += `${key}:${count[key]} `;
  }
  result4.textContent = result;
}
```

```html
<label for="sarcina4"> Enter text</label>
<br>
<textarea name="sarcina4" id="sarc4" cols="60" rows="5"></textarea>
<br>
<button onclick="ex44()">Afisare</button>
<p id="result4"></p>
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `+=` on `.textContent` either - just accumulate into a string and update the DOM _once_.