# Input in a label created via javascript is not checked

Tags: javascript, html

My `html` and Javascript is as below:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const label = document.createElement('label')
const input = document.createElement('input')

input.type = 'checkbox'
input.checked = true

label.appendChild(input)
label.innerHTML += 'This is a label'

container.appendChild(label)
```

```html
<html>

<body>
    <div id = 'container'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

The result is that I just get an unchecked checkbox in the label. However, if I remove the label from the equation and just append the input to the container, then it is pre-checked as expected. How come setting `input.checked = true` has no effect when the input is in a label?

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const input = document.createElement('input')

input.type = 'checkbox'
input.checked = true

container.appendChild(input)
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id='container'></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: See also here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595808/is-it-possible-to-append-to-innerhtml-without-destroying-descendants-event-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The line:

```
label.innerHTML += 'This is a label'
```

takes your existing `innerHTML` and re-writes it, destroying any (non-delegated) event-handlers or existing properties.

If, instead of `label.appendChild()`, you use:

```
label.append(input, 'This is a label');
```

Then it works to add the text as well as the `<input>` to the `<label>`:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const label = document.createElement('label')
const input = document.createElement('input')

input.type = 'checkbox'
input.checked = true

label.append(input, 'This is a label');

container.appendChild(label)
```

```html
<div id='container'></div>
```

References:

- [`Element.append()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append).

Answer (score 2):

In place of using `innerHTML`, which doesn't work well when adding siblings since it destroys and recreates the parent element, it's better using `appendChild` and add the sibling as a `TextNode`:

```js
const container = document.getElementById('container')

const label = document.createElement('label')
const input = document.createElement('input')

input.type = 'checkbox'
input.checked = true

label.appendChild(input)
label.appendChild(document.createTextNode("This is a label")); 

container.appendChild(label)
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id = 'container'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This will also prevent script injection whether you'll decide, in the future, to allow users decide the label.

Answer (score -3):

You're missing a ";" after each line, so that is a problem.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't require semicolons